# Tips for golfing in Befunge 93

Tags: code-golf, tips, befunge

What general tips do you have for golfing in Befunge 93? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Befunge 93 (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: There's already a [Befunge 98](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16090/tips-for-golfing-in-befunge-98) topic

Answer (score 1):

As little white space as possible.

If you have a 10x5 (50) code, can you make it into a 6x8 (48):

```
some code 
goes here 
and it is 
exactly 50
characters
```

goes to

```
put a bi
t of cod
e here a
nd count
all of 4
0 chars!
```