# Lolololololololololololol

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence

**Let us take a break from the brain-wrecking questions and answer some of the simpler ones**

You have recently read something extremely funny, and want to express your laughter to the world! *But how can you?*

### Task

You have to display the string:
`Lolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololol...`

...to STDOUT.

The string *should be of infinite length*, or *will constantly be printed until the end of time*.

It is just as simple!

But remember, this is `code-golf`, so the source code must be as short as possible!

*Note: Some languages may throw errors since excecution  can be timed out, or for other reasons. That is okay! It can be weird when you laugh forever!*

---

Good luck!

Comment: Why not all caps? LOL is an acronym afater all.

Comment: That is the main challenge though. (There should be a capital at the start) Also, most people type "Lol" instead of "LOL".

Comment: Fair enough, I guess it does add a little twist.

Comment: By the way, standard site rules will allow functions which return the result (e.g. in an infinite generator) making the print to STDOUT part redundant unless you specify that this must be a full program (which I'd advise against, but is allowed).

Comment: [possibleduplicate.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200306/scream-very-loudly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scream very loudly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200306/scream-very-loudly)

Comment: @Razetime I have not asked to constantly output a unique character. My aim was to recieve programs which switch between the characters 'l' and 'o' WITH an 'L' at the start.

Comment: Sadly, that does not change the challenge enough to be a unique question.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. The other challenge is much simpler.

Comment: @thedefault. I don't understand your comment. The difference (requires an extra character to be outputted before the program, and outputs two characters instead of one) is fairly trivial. As you can see, if we remove the print `L` part and change `ol` to `A`, we get an SVL answer!

Comment: I have reopened this question. I believe the small difference presents interesting golfing opportunities in some languages and, furthermore, that simply porting a solution might well not be competitive. One only needs to look at a few of the answers to see some interesting differences. If people disagree then by all means vote to close again.

Comment: almost a trick: 10/99

Answer (score 27):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```python
x='L'
while[print(end=x)]:x='ol'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8JW3UedqzwjMyc1uqAoM69EIzUvxbZCM9YKKJOfo/7/PwA)

In Python 3, the `print` function by default has `end='\n'` to put a newline after what you print. Rather than changing that to the empty string, we stick the value `x` that we want to be printed there, and don't provide any value to be printed.

We stick the printing in the `while` loop condition. Since `print` returns `None` by default but this is Falsey and won't continue the loop, we wrap it in a singleton list to make it Truthy.

I had tried to stick an infinite iterator into `print` like `print(*iter(...),sep='')`, but it looks like Python will consume the whole iterable first and never actually print.

Comment: I wonder why I didn't think of this when I put the printing in the condition in my Jelly answer :/

Comment: Ruby, 23 bytes - 

x='L';x='ol'while $><<x

(Can't post because it's marked as duplicate. Nice trick!)

Answer (score 23):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 8 bytes

```
"loL",<,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9Xysn3UdKx0fn/HwA)

#### How?

***`Lo`***:
Initially the IP is going *east*.
`"loL"` pushes *`l`*, *`o`* and *`L`* to the stack.
`,` prints *`L`*, `<` turns the IP *west* and `,` prints *`o`*.

***`lo`*** forever:
The IP is now moving *west*.
`"loL"` pushes *`L`*, *`o`* and *`l`* to the stack.
The IP wraps around and `,<,` prints *`l`* and *`o`*.
*`L`* is left on the stack, but since we usually assume infinite resources, this is fine.

Answer (score 22):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 5 bytes

```
L;o>l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9/HOt8u5/9/AA)

*Hexagony golfing language confirmed*

For some reason I was looking at [my own answer that prints "six" in 6 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195264/78410) and randomly thought "what if I remove `@`?", and exactly got this answer. 4 bytes is impossible because `Lol;` is already 4 bytes and it is impossible to alternate two chars and print both in a single loop without redirection.

Since there is no "halt" command in this program, the program flow looks like this: (It is recommended to read the docs on how `>` redirects the PC)

```
 A B
C > D
 E F

    [.....................................]  <= looping region
A B C > C B A D > A D B F > F C E A > D E F C > C ...
L ; o   o ; L l   L l ; .   . o . L   l . . o   o
^ ^     ^ ^         ^ ^
```

After the initial `L;`, `o;` and `l;` appear in the big loop in that order, therefore printing `Lololol...`.

Answer (score 18):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>13</del> 10 bytes

```
00000000: b04c cd29 0c20 3403 ebf8                 .L.). 4...
```

Listing:

```
B0 4C       MOV  AL, 'L'        ; start off with capital L
        PRINT:
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write to console
0C 20       OR   AL, 20H        ; lowercase it
34 03       XOR  AL, 3          ; swap between 'l' (0x6c) and 'o' (0x6f)
EB F8       JMP  PRINT          ; loop forever
```

[Try it online!](http://twt86.co/?c=sEzNKQwgNAPr%2BA%3D%3D)

A standalone PC DOS executable COM program. Output to console.

**-3 bytes thx to @nununoisy's very clever use of `XOR` to swap between `l` and `o`.**

Runtime:

[image]

*Forever and ever...*

Comment: 10 bytes:

`B0 4C   mov al, 'L'`

`PRINT:`

`CD 29    int 29h`

`0C 20    or al,0x20`

`34 03    xor al,3`

`EB F8    jmp PRINT`

Comment: @nununoisy oh that's very clever! Updated with credit given!

Answer (score 11):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

-1 byte thanks @ovs

```
+[+<[-<]>>++]<.>>+[+>+[<]>->]<[.---.+++]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1rbJlrXJtbOTls71kYPSEVrAzFQQNcu1iZaT1dXV08bKPX/PwA)

Comment: You don't the initial `>`, at least for the interpreter you linked, since it uses a wrapping tape.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know that.

Comment: I found a shorter version using [KSab](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15858/ksab)'s [bfbrute](https://github.com/ksabry/bfbrute): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1rbTlc3WlvbTltb28Ym1s5OO9ZGz84uWs9Ozyb2/38A "brainfuck – Try It Online")

Comment: @ovs Do you have any tips on how to use bfbrute.

Comment: Not really, I should just used it the first time. I halved the size parameters in *Main.cpp*, because the string is smaller than `Hello World!`. It seems to continuously output brute force attempts, to stop it I ran it with `./bin/bfbrute  | head -n 10000000 | sort | head -n 10`. This takes the first 10 million attempts and outputs the shortest 10.

Comment: [bfcrunch](https://github.com/primo-ppcg/BF-Crunch) does a bit better at [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNzraRtcOBLXtdG1sbGLttIFIzy5aW09XV1dPWzv2/38A)

Comment: @JoKing the *bfbrute* result I commented is 30 bytes long.

Answer (score 11):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 7 bytes

```
762
8.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3MyIy0LP@P9/AA)

Adds `623 % 256 == 111` to the previous answers below.

```
76   Push 76 and turn right (three-way junction)
.    Pop and print % 256 as char (L)
     Now the top is 0, so it should go straight, but instead it reflects to North
623  Turn right at 6 and push 623, going around the corners
.    Pop and print % 256 as char (o); go straight (three-way junction)
876  Push 876
     Loop forever, printing "lo"
```

---

### 10 bytes

```
76
8.1
 11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3IzLQs@QS8HQ8P9/AA)

Same idea, but using `876 % 256 == 108`. Turns out that going from an uppercase to lowercase is just a matter of prepending a 8 because `800 % 256 == 32`. At the center junction, the top is always 0 right after pop and print, so the IP goes straight (first from north to south, and second from east to west). All the numbers are corners which turn the IP 90 degrees, so the overall path is infinity-shaped `76.111.876.111. ...`. This form is one byte shorter than the naive square loop:

### 11 bytes

```
76.
8 1
.11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3EyPy0LBkEvP0PD/fwA)

---

### 14 bytes

```
 7
.63
1 1
11.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fwZxLz8yYy1DBkMvQUO//fwA)

#### How it works

First, the flow: the execution starts at the first valid command, which is `7` on top. The only junction is `6`, and since it causes the top of stack to be positive, the IP always turns right. It turns 180 degrees if it hits a dead end. So the sequence of commands executed in order is:

```
76.111.13676.111.13676.111. ...(runs indefinitely)
```

The stack has implicit zeros, and each of `0-9` adds that digit to the end of the top of the stack (in other words, `n` changes the top number `x` to `10x + n`). So the program is supposed to print the characters with charcode 76, 111, 13676, 111, 13676, ...

But 13676 is not `l`! Actually, Labyrinth's character output is done modulo 256.

How did I find such a number? With the path designed like this

```
 7
.6?
1 ?
11.
```

The problem is to find a number `??676` that is same as `l` (108) modulo 256. Note that, the equation `??xxx == yyy modulo 256` (`x` and `y` are givens and `?`s are unknown) is solvable if `xxx == yyy modulo 8`, and if so, it always has a solution within two or fewer digits, in particular `0 <= ?? < 32`. Since `676 % 8 == 108 % 8 == 4`, this is solvable, and the solution here is `13`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 23 bytes

```bash
(echo L&yes)|tr "
y" ol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/XyM1OSNfwUetMrVYs6akSEGJq1JJIT/n/38A)

#### Explanation

We can generate infinite output using `yes`: without arguments, it outputs an infinite stream of `y` separated by newlines. `echo L & yes` outputs an `L` first, so our output stream looks like

```bash
L
y
y
y
y
```

To turn this into the output we want, we just need to change newline to `o` and `y` to `l`. `tr "\ny" ol` does this transliteration, and we can save a further byte by using an actual newline in place of `\n`.

Comment: Although `'\ny'` is longer, you can use `\\ny` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 13 bytes

```hs
'L':cycle"ol"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX91H3Sq5MjknVSk/R@l/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkYKKQtr/f8lpOYnpxf91I5wDAgA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```java
a->{for(var s="L";;s="ol")System.out.print(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETvfsWSU3LQHwj2LrQnj6WHrUaJVSPZNVDEb0@DiHQOM7A7PGbAgPnQfuKyvkfbQDMiETzQzrBlGSTZmY3vsDFQpROcCs62YEDW7O3cAyp9vPbDTxYxcoqjOiXiWX6@AH1P6o9WgYUSIua3rXNeBvRApbgLrVO4Uaj6S2ymwq1cLInBkpTeo74AtjBSiGvEHn8)

thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) and [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) helping me save 4 and 1 byte(s) respectively!

Comment: Does [this](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETvfsWSU3LQHwj2LrQnj6WHrUZZq0ayUSjit6chiHQOO7A789gBN8yH9hOW9T1SA82IzPBAmmHPMoii2RvXYWOgiis4tVlqwYCsvaO5B1Q6nY40TxZ79NFSdIrEM/x8Abqe1R@tAoISAue3vbNOcinuQutodhSq/rI3U2FXXyyx7yUrfQR9lakwUojrgSP8AA) count?

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>8</strike> 6 bytes

ovs' far superior 6-byter:

```
„Lo[?l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8n/xo@5z//wE)

**Explanation:**

```
„Lo     Push 2-char string onto stack ('lo')
   [    Begin infinite loop
    ?   Output with no newline
     l  Push lowercase of top of stack ('Lo' -> 'lo')
        (Implicitly close infinite loop)
```

---

[05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

My pitiful 8-byter:

```
'L?„ol[?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3cf@UcO8/Jxo@///AQ)

<strike>It might still be golfable, perhaps if there's a way to compress 'Lol' even further.</strike>

**Explanation:**

```
'L        Push 'L' onto stack
  ?       Print without newline ('L')
   „ol    Push 2-char string onto stack ('ol')
      [   Loop Forever
       ?  Print without newline ('ol')
          (Implicitly close infinite loop)
```

Comment: Ah of course, How could I have missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Generally, low length strings are too much of a hassle to compress without sacrificing golfiness.

Comment: My idea was [`„olÞ'Lš`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8/JzD89R9ji78/x8A), good job!

Answer (score 8):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md), 14 <del>31</del> bytes

```
6C
6F@0
@0/\4C
```

Marbelous is a language based on marble machines

- `@n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) is a portal which teleport the marble to another portal with the same value
- `00`-`FF` initiate a marble with this value
- `/\` create a duplicate passing marble to it's left and right
- `..` is a noop
- marbles going out of the machine from the bottom are implicitly outputed

[interpretor](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py)

-17 bytes thanks to DLosc

Comment: I *think* this three-line version should work: `6C`, `6F@0`, `@0/\4C` (14 bytes). I'm not 100% sure because I tried running Marbelous by putting the source code into Try It Online's Python 2 interpreter, where it seemed oddly nondeterministic--sometimes it just output `L`, sometimes `Loo`, sometimes `Loooooo` infinitely, and sometimes `Lololololol` infinitely. But since your original code did the same things, I'm reasonably confident the golfed version works correctly.

Comment: @DLosc you're right it works, thank :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>37</s>  34 bytes

-3 thanks to xnor - noting that print may have no unnamed argument!

```python
x='L'
while x:x=print(end=x)or'ol'
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8JW3UedqzwjMydVwdCqwragKDOvRCM1L8W2QjO/SD0/R/3/fwA)**

Comment: Nice assignment trick! You can do `print(end=x)`.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 24 bytes

```
L<?php for(;;)echo'ol';
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fx8a@IKNAIS2/SMPaWjM1OSNfKT9Hyfr/fwA "PHP – Try It Online") using a for loop.

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fx8a@IKNAIS2/SMPaWjM1OSNfIT/H@v9/AA) by using `ol` instead of `'ol'` and a for loop.

Answer (score 7):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 147 bytes

```
haha l-o-l funny!i saw a thingy,it was soo funny
o?what
i am crying
o?what
i am dying,literal CHOKING
dying r-n?goddamn
just see
ohhhhhh heh,lol ig
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?VcoxDgIhEIXhnlM8ezjDFhZqTPQM44LMGJZJgA3h9Kuula/83s/EhOTUJTzXnMdBUKmD0FhyHFYaOlVU1d9vdOpMzQhowVzGJ/oj/xWbpIVCCcfz/Xq5ncyuKC5PUb2nJZvXWhtqCEZ5HziwTZogcdse5N8)

In the form of a text conversation between two people collectively laughing at something they found online.

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

```c
f(i){f(!printf("Lol"+!i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOk1DsaAoM68kTUPJJz9HSVsxU1PTuvY/UEQhNzEzT0NToZqLM01D05qLsyi1pLQoT8HAmqv2PwA)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 10 bytes

```
['L'}'lo'}
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiWydMJ30nbG8nfSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIifQ==)

Visualization (separated)

[image: Visualization (separated)]

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: Seems to be an interesting bug where having two string on the same line make both of them generators (e.g. `'lo'>'L'}`)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”L⁾olȮ¿
```

A full program which prints an `L` then repeatedly prints `ol`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw1yfR4378nNOrDu0//9/AA)**

#### How?

```
”L⁾olȮ¿ - Main Link: no arguments
”L      - set the left argument to 'L'
      ¿ - while...
     Ȯ  - ...condition: print & yield the left argument
  ⁾ol   - ...do: set the left argument to "ol"
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

-5 thanks to @Bubbler

```
L;o;l;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9/HOt86x/r/fwA)

```
  L ;   Executed once: Set memory to 'L' (76) and print
 o ; l  Executed repeatedly: Set memory to 'o' (111), print, set memory to 'l' (108)
  ; .   Executed repeatedly: Print
```

After the first row is executed once, the second and third rows are repeatedly executed, infinitely printing `ol`.

Comment: Simply `L;o;l;` works. Not sure if it can be reduced to 5 bytes, but it might be possible.

Answer (score 6):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), <s>22</s> 14 bytes

```
@o|
.l@
L"^
/"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/3yG/hksvx4HLRymOS1/p/38A)

-8 thanks to Jo King.

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/P0ffgctBT48rLt@HS0ExjktP8f9/AA), taking advantage of multiple starting points

Comment: Wait, what am i doing, we should be using `"` to print instead: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/3yG/hksvx4HLRymOS1/p/38A)

Answer (score 5):

#### **x86-16 machine code MS-DOS - 23 bytes**

This answer inspired by [640KB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/lolololololololololololol/210988#210988) answer.

```
 000000: B4 02 B7 4C 8A D7 CD 21  B2 6F CD 21 8A D7 80 F2   ...L...!.o.!....
 000010: 20 CD 21 EB F3 CD 20                                .!...
```

Listing:

```
      6 0100  B4 02              MOV AH, 02H
      7 0102  B7 4C              MOV BH, 'L'
      8 0104  8A D7              MOV DL, BH
      9 0106  CD 21              INT 21H
     10
     11 0108                 PRINT:
     12 0108  B2 6F              MOV DL, 'o'
     13 010A  CD 21              INT 21H
     14 010C  8A D7              MOV DL, BH
     15 010E  80 F2 20           XOR DL, 20H
     16 0111  CD 21              INT 21H
     17 0113  EB F3              JMP PRINT
     18
     19 0115  CD 20              INT 20H
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: The `INT 20H` at the end seems unnecessary. Also, `MOV DL, BH` (with or without the `XOR DL, 20H`) takes far too many bytes. Just move the constant into `DH` directly. Also move the `PRINT:` back one instruction to save yourself an `INT 21H`.

Answer (score 5):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), 12 bytes

```
76.28524+[.]
```

Prints the byte streams `76` once, then `28524` forever

Answer (score 5):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org) `+startinsert`, <s><sup>14</sup></s> 11 bytes

```
ol<C-v><C-r>"<C-o>ddL<C-r>"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/uf@T8/R0xIiT8lxUdI6f9/AA)

In TIO, when the recursive register expansion (RRE) times out, nothing is outputted since it didn't finish expanding. In Vim, you may not see anything right away since the console might freeze during the RRE, but if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you can stop the expansion and see that it does work.

Explanation:

```
                              # '+startinsert' flag - start vim in insert mode; TIO equivalent is 'i' in the header
ol<C-v><C-r>"                 # Insert 'ol<C-r>"'
              <C-o>           # Run normal mode command, then return to insert mode:
                   dd         #   Delete 'ol<C-r>"' into unnamed register
                     L        # Insert 'L'
                      <C-r>"  # Insert unnamed register, which recursively expands to 'ol' + unnamed register
```

Answer (score 5):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), two answers of 33 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(;;)printf s=s?"ol":"L"}
```

and

```
BEGIN{for(printf"L";;)printf"ol"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9f2cnV3dOvOi2/SMPaWrOgKDOvJE2h2LbYXik/R8lKyUeplgtJCUQeKApXC1JW@/8/AA) (uncomment a line to try it)

First answer: a simple ternary condition upon the assignment of the variable `s`. On the first run, it is evaluated as false. As it is not assigned yet, it is parsed as a null string, which is false.

Second answer: just a for loop.

Answer (score 5):

## [Flipbit](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Flipbit), <s><sup>35</sup></s> <s><sup>30</sup></s> 28 bytes

*Thanks to Bubbler for -5 by shortening the loop*

*Thanks to ovs for -2 by being big smort*

```
^>>>^>^>>.<<<<<^>>>[>^>^.<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/P87Ozi4OCO30bEAAxI0GCQC5sf//AwA)

Prints `L`, gets the tape set up for `l`, then makes use of the fact that `o` and `l` differ by only their two least significant bits to create a short loop to print both characters repeatedly.

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/P87Ozi4OCO304mzibIAAJBAN5cb@/w8A)

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks! I wondered if the loop could be shortened, but I couldn’t figure out how to do it.

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/P87Ozi4OCO30bEAAxI0GCQC5sf//AwA) by setting up `l` instead of `o` before the loop.

Answer (score 5):

## [Forte (Forter)](https://github.com/judofyr/forter), 25 bytes

```
5PRINT"ol";:LET5=1
1PUT76
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/980IMjTL0QpP0fJ2srHNcTU1pDLMCA0xNzs/38A)

#### Explanation

An undefined behavior exploit courtesy of [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king):

```
1 PUT 76
```

Print an `L` character.

```
5 PRINT "ol"; : LET 5 = 1
```

Print `ol` without a final newline, and set 5 to 1.

Apparently, this overwrites the former line 1 with the former line 5, and thus (lacking an `END` statement) the `PRINT "ol";` line is executed repeatedly forever. But I don't really understand how this works--especially since it only works if you write line 5 before line 1, not [vice versa](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/98wIDTE3IzLNCDI0y9EKT9HydrKxzXE1Nbw/38A)...

---

Here's a **44-byte** version that doesn't use any undefined behavior:

```
1PUT76
5PRINT"ol";:LET6=6+0
6LET0=2:LET5=5+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/98wIDTE3IzLNCDI0y9EKT9HydrKxzXEzNZM24DLDMgysDUCCZjammob/f8PAA)

#### Explanation

```
1 PUT 76
```

Print an `L` character.

```
5 PRINT "ol"; : LET 6 = 6 + 0
```

Print `ol` without a final newline, and set 6 to 6.

```
6 LET 0 = 2 : LET 5 = 5 + 2
```

Set 0 to 2, and set 5 to 7.

```
5 7 PRINT "ol"; : LET 6 = 6 + 0 2
```

Print `ol` again, and set 6 to 8.

```
6 8 LET 0 2 = 2 : LET 5 7 = 5 7 + 2
```

Set 2 to 2, and set 7 to 9.

```
5 7 9 PRINT "ol"; : LET 6 8 = 6 8 + 0 2
```

Print `ol` again, and set 8 to 10.

And so on forever.

Comment: Or take advantage of undefined behaviour: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/980IMjTL0QpP0fJ2srHNcTU1pDLMCA0RMHc7P9/AA "Forte – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing Haha! I was just going by the Esolangs article, which sort of implies that "undefined behavior" == "error", so I didn't try it. (Reassigning the current line number is undefined behavior too.)

Comment: @JoKing Upon looking at it more closely, I find your second one really weird--do you know why it only works when line 5 is written before line 1?

Comment: it looks like the ruby interpreter has this line: `@lines.min_by { |line| posclamp(evaluate(line.number) - num) }`, which will take the first line in the program that matches the criteria

Answer (score 5):

Neither beats Johan du Toit's answer, but I enjoy that they are full programs, plus I like the way the longjmp answer works.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

As straight forward as it gets, uses `for` initializer to print `L`, then it's `ol`s from there on out.

```c
main(){for(printf("L");printf("ol"););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6Lb9Io6AoM68kTUPJR0nTGsbOzwFyNK1r//8HAA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

Definitely more fun, use an int array as jmp_buf, then add the return of setjmp to the string pointer so that the first iteration adds 0, then pass 1 to longjmp so the rest add 1 and skip the `L`.

Thanks to jdt for -4 bytes!

```c
j[9];main(){printf("Lol"+setjmp(j));longjmp(j,1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8r2jLWOjcxM09Ds7qgKDOvJE1DySc/R0m7OLUkK7dAI0tT0zonPy8dzNYx1LSu/f8fAA)

Comment: +1 for the longjmp. This also works for a full program `main(i){main(!printf("Lol"+!i));}`

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8r2jLWOjcxM09Ds7qgKDOvJE1DySc/R0m7OLUkK7dAI0tT0zonPy8dzNYx1LSu/f8fAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 200 bytes

```
  ^     ^
 / \   / \
/out\ /do \
-----^-----^
    / \   ^-
   /chr\ / \
  ^-----/out\
 / \   ^-----^
/76 \ / \   ^-
-----/chr\ / \
    ^-----/chr\
   / \   ^-----
  /111\ / \
  -----/108\
       -----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1LCoAwDET3OcVcoMRu1MOUgqhQF0Xxs/D0tTF@OouQDO@R5Vy7OA1m68MYx5QAD4knMFxe8iSej92BhznvRuJ1EhQQ3sjBfVjdrUgjuVX6INW4qeF@UcFC/WTpqPghyTdba19WQVu1KuJpUroA)

This *seems* to be the shortest way that I can find. This language isn't easy to golf in.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
p\L#p"ol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vyDGR7lAKT/n/38A)

### Explanation

```
p\L#p"ol
p\L        : print "L"
   #       : while True:
    p"ol   :     print "ol"
```

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB/Octave, <s>38 35 33</s> 31 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to flawr*
*-2 bytes thanks to tsh*

```matlab
"L";while fprintf(ans);"ol";end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f9fyUfJujwjMydVIa2gKDOvJE0jMa9Y01opP0fJOjUv5f9/AA)
In MATLAB the output in GUI command window is truncated, but the code itself executes forever. Maybe if you run script from actual command prompt it will actually display new `ol`s infinitely. Dunno, didn't try. Online Octave implementations I tried (tio.run & octave-online.net) *obiously* kill the execution of script at some point.
Also, if you decide to run this in MATLAB, use Ctrl+C to stop, because clicking Pause won't do anything.

Comment: Nice, you can shorten it a little bit using `x="L";while fprintf(x);x="ol";end`

Comment: `"L";while fprintf(ans);"ol";end` is shorter

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 5 bytes

```
L,{ǪȽ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fR6f6@KoTe///BwA)

Finally! A reasonable use for the push'n'print commands!

### Explained

- Print the letter "L" (`L,`)
- While true: (`{`)
- ---- Print the letter "o" (`Ǫ`)
- ---- Print the letter "l" (`Ƚ`)

Comment: There's a push and print command for every letter?!

Comment: @Razetime yep.... It's a result of _Bad Choices™_

Answer (score 4):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 18 bytes

```
og,!<
\l@>\<
2:L!_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/Pz9dR9GGKybHwS7GhsvIykcx/v///7pF/3UzAQ) (requires the `-i` flag)

### Explanation

Flobnar is a 2D language where expressions are laid out geometrically. For example, for a program that computes the number 10, you might write:

```
5
+  @
5
```

Here, `@` indicates the entry point for the program, and has the effect of evaluating the term to its west; `+` evaluates the terms to the north and south and returns their sum; etc.

The basic idea for this program is to embed the characters 'o', 'l', and 'L' in the source code at coordinates `(0, 0)`, `(1, 1)`, and `(2, 2)` respectively. Execution proceeds roughly like this:

```python
def step(n):
    step(!n if (!putchar(get(n, n))) else "impossible since putchar() returns 0")

step(2)
```

Here's what the program looks like ungolfed:

```
o    >>>>v
 l   ^ \ < \ @
  L    v   2
     :!_
  :
  g , !<
  :
```

See [the specification](https://github.com/catseye/Flobnar) for more detailed information about what each term does.

Comment: Note that this requires `-i`, so I don't think it works for the [reference implementation](https://github.com/catseye/Flobnar/tree/master/src).

Comment: @Wezl I don't think the reference implementation even supports character IO.

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 14 bytes

```
76P[[ol]Pdx]dx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/cLCA6Oj8nNiClIjal4v9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `5`, 9 bytes

```
\L₴{`ol`₴
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%5CL%E2%82%B4%7B%60ol%60%E2%82%B4&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [8 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%5CL%E2%82%B4%7B%E2%80%9Bol%E2%82%B4&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [7 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9BLo%7B%3A%E2%82%B4%E2%87%A9&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) and [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 10 bytes

```
"volL
:>o$
```

[Try it online! (><>)](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X6ksP8eHy8ouX@X/fwA)

[Try it online! (Gol><>)](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X6ksP8eHy8ouX@X/fwA)

#### How it works

```
"volL    Push charcodes of v, o, l, L in that order (L is at the top)
"v       End string mode
 >       and move to the second row
  o      Pop and print one char (initially L)
: o$     Infinite loop: Swap, dup, pop and print one char
```

Answer (score 4):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 13 bytes

```
'L,[1]["ol"]#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/1/dRyfaMDZaKT9HKVb5/38A)

### Explanation

```
'L, // outputs "L" character
[1] // pushes lambda which evaluates to 1 onto the stack
["ol"] // pushes lambda which prints "ol" onto the stack
#   // Executes lambda on top of stack while the lambda below it
    // does not evaluate to zero
```

Note: This is my first post on this site, so let me know in the comments if I did something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer! Doesn't look like you did anything wrong, the formatting and explanation are better than most of my answers :p

Comment: @Redwolf Programs Thanks for your feedback! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>60</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)

-1 byte by replacing `while(1)` with `for(;;)`

-1 byte thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

```javascript
for((p=x=>process.stdout.write(...x))`L`;;)p`ol`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDYAgDADAdeBhFyA4gUOUACYQY5u2KtvXu1neolUG23ZT6@4nSQicV95ZqHZVUGv0GHwyrAcAWDHigSlFRrrQ/Qc)

Answer (score 4):

## [WedgeScript](https://github.com/WedgeScript/WedgeScript), 9 bytes

```
'Lo|"ol"o
```

Explanation:

```
'L         Pushes the character literal L to the stack
o          Output 
|          Loop the rest of the code infinitely
"ol"       Push the string "ol" to the stack
o          Output
```

Yes, Wedgescript is a custom language made by me, here is the repo with interpreter install instructions: [github.com/WedgeScript/WedgeScript](https://github.com/WedgeScript/WedgeScript)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I've cleaned up the formatting of your answer a bit to make it easier to read the explanation. This language looks really cool! I think I might have to check it out!

Answer (score 4):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 30 bytes

```
v001000<   ~010!

~1011000110^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/7/MwMDQwMDARkFBoQ7IUuTiqjM0MAQJAYm4//8B)

Outputs as a stream of bits.

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/7/MwMDQwMDARkFBoQ7IUuTiqjM0MAQJAYm4//8B) while still avoiding the undefined behaviour of outputting two bits at the same time

Answer (score 4):

## [Minim](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minim), <strike>41</strike> 39 Bytes

New solution prepends 3 to the string, saving 2 bytes:

```
[]=3&"loL".$<[[0]--].[0]=[0]?[0]:2.C=0.
```

With whitespace and comments:

```
[] = 3 & "loL".      ; Inserts the value 3, and the string "Lol" backwards, into \
                       memory from index 0
$< [[0]--].          ; Prints the value at the index stored at index 0 as unicode, \
                       and decrements index 0
[0] = [0] ? [0] : 2. ; Sets index 0 back to 2 if it equals 0
C = 0.               ; Sets the program counter to 0, which advances to 1 afterwards
```

Old solution used ASCII escape character 0x3 (ETX) in the string:

```
[]="\x03loL".$<[[0]--].[0]=[0]?[0]:2.C=0.
```

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KakkoiiChris/Minim)

Answer (score 4):

## Turing Machine, 29 bytes

```
0 _ L r 1
1 _ o r 2
2 _ l r 1
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?d07a505400fb273edf1e6348b1b26f1f)

Answer (score 4):

## [makina](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/makina), 14 bytes

```
v<<
>P^
 >tlo;
```

I AM BUTTER FEED ME BOT

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! I feel like I've seen you before though...

Comment: @ButterFactory rewrite your responses to - oh wait wrong bot

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
:'L¢"ol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/30rd59Aipfyc//8B)

**Commented:**

```hs
:         -- prepend
 'L       -- the character L
   ¢      -- to the infinitely repeated
    "ol"  -- string "ol" (closing quote not required)
```

Equivalent to this Haskell function:

```hs
(:) 'L' (cycle "ol")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX8NKU0HdR11BI7kyOSdVQSk/R0nzf25iZp6CrUJBaUlwSZFC2v9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Answer (score 3):

## [StupidStackLanguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StupidStackLanguage), 26 bytes

```
avqvvmifavvqimiqdddltflflu
```

[Try it online!](https://www.lebster.xyz/projects/stustala/#5f7046a8302a837e956eab78)

Comment: This sounds like an interesting language!

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth),  <s>29</s>  26 bytes

```
7 :::.:+
6 1  # #
.11  -:.
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXMHKykrPSpvLTMFQQUFZQZlLzxDI0LXS@/8fAA)**

#### How?

Labyrinth starts with the instruction pointer at the top left and executes the character underneath, performing actions on the top of the main stack (and an auxiliary stack, not used here). After executing an instruction the instruction pointer then moves in a direction which is dependent on how many neighbouring instructions there are (spaces are not instructions) and the value of the top of the main stack. As such this code does the following:

```
7 - pop (implicit 0), multiply by 10 and add seven    main stack: [7]
6 - pop (y), multiply by 10 and add six                           [76]
. - pop (76), print that byte ('L')                               []
1 - pop (implicit 0), multiply by 10 and add one                  [1]
1 - pop (1), multiply by 10 and add one                           [11]
1 - pop (11), multiply by 10 and add one                          [111]
: - duplicate the top of the main stack                           [111,111]
: - duplicate the top of the main stack                           [111,111,111]
: - duplicate the top of the main stack                           [111,111,111,111]
. - pop (111), print that byte ('o')                              [111,111,111]
    three neighbours (::#), positive top of main -> turn
# - push depth of main stack                                      [3,111,111,111]
- - pop (b=3), pop (a=111), subtract (a-b=108), push              [108,111,111]
: - duplicate the top of the main stack                           [108,108,111,111]
. - pop (108), print that byte ('l')                              [108,111,111]
# - push depth of main stack                                      [3,108,111,111]
+ - pop (b=3), pop (a=108), add (a+b=111), push                   [111,111,111]
: - duplicate the top of the main stack                           [111,111,111,111]
. - pop (111), print that byte ('o')                              [111,111,111]
    three neighbours (::#), positive top of main -> turn
# - ...now we will continue to print 'l' then 'o' ad-infinitum
```

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fwZxLz8yYy1DBkMvQUO//fwA) using `13676%256 == 108`.

Comment: That's really neat, don't you want to post it yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately the question was closed as duplicate...

Comment: I've reopened the question and commented about why under the question.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
@set/p=L<nul
:g
@set/p=ol<nul
@goto g
```

`set/p` outputs the string after the `=` as the prompt, and then expects to read from the console, which ends the line when you hit enter. But we redirect the input, so no enter happens, and we simply end up with a infinite series of "prompts" all on one line. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @T3RROR.

Comment: -2 bytes by changing  each `@set/ps=` to `@set/p=`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
#0[ol,$Output~WriteString~#]&@L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/1/ZIDo/R0fFv7SkoLSkLrwosyQ1uKQoMy@9TjlWzcHn/38A)

Stops when the program hits the `$IterationLimit`, which defaults to `4096`.

**34 bytes** does the job without worrying about that:

```
Do[$Output~WriteString~L;L=ol,∞]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lP1rFv7SkoLSkLrwosyQ1uKQoMy@9zsfaxzY/R@dRx7zY//8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 7 bytes

```
L(@o@l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fR8Mh3yFH8/9/AA)

```
L(@o@l)
L          Pushes character literal 'L'
 (    )    Loop while top of stack:
  @            Output top of stack as character ('L' first iteration, 'l' otherwise)
   o@          Output 'o'
     l         Push 'l', repeating the loop
```

Comment: Fun fact: This language inspired me to make this challenge. In fact, the first program I wrote in !@#$%^&*()_+ was a LOLOL program (it printed the capitalized version though). Today it survives in its [esolang article](https://esolangs.org/wiki/!@$%25%5E%26*()%2B).

Comment: @SunnyMoon I'm honored :D What a bizarre coincidence, I haven't posted on this site in almost a year.

Comment: Welcome back, Conor :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Golang](https://golang.org/), <s>53</s> 27 bytes

```
print("L");for{print("ol")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8///78gMTk7MT1VITcxM4@LK600LxnM1NCsLijKzCvRUPJR0rROyy@CcfNzlDRra///BwA)

EDIT: Apparently `package main` and `func main()` don't necessarily count towards the byte count for Go e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107159/95793.

Previous version:

```
package main
func main(){print("L");for{print("ol")}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 chars, 16 bytes

Per standard rules, an infinite generator is acceptable.

```raku
{|<L ol>,~*…*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/usbGRyE/x06nTutRwzKt2v/WXFzFiZUKaRqa0QZ6eiYGsf8B)

Since this can be directly assigned or passed into other functions, the brackets aren't per se necessary but not sure if I can do that (if so, -2 chars/bytes).  Enforcing the standard out bit is as simple as add a `>>.print` adds an extra 8 chars (22 chars, 24 bytes total).

```raku
(|<L ol>,~*…*)>>.print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@jxsZHIT/HTqdO61HDMi1NOzu9gqLMvJL//wE)

Answer (score 3):

## C# 9, <s>55</s> 47 bytes

```csharp
for(var x="L";;x="ol")System.Console.Write(x);
```

Thanks, @ceilingcat!

*Previously on **Code Golf***

```csharp
var x="L";while(true){System.Console.Write(x);x="ol";}
```

[Using top-level statements.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)

[Microsoft's online compiler that doesn't like this infinite loop idea...](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would it be possible for you to add in a link to an online interpreter, such as [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/#), so others can run your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only .NET 5.0 online interpreter is on Microsoft's site. This doesn't allow for injecting code. Plus, it locks up on this infinite loop. I'll add the link, but best of luck getting it to run.

Comment: @ceilingcat ooo... I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin(script)](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>23</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```kotlin
print("L")while(0<1)print("ol")
```

In Kotlin you need a top level declaration(main function) in order to compile code but Kotlin compiler also allows compiling Kotlin scripts using `kotlinc -script lol.kts` so yes you can compile one liners without top level direction using a file. this cannot be verified using TIO the only online compiler that I found for Kotlin scripting or Kotlin REPL is [**this site**](https://replit.com/languages/kotlin).
In order to test this use command line in right side of the given site and and run the code in these steps:

First create a file:

```bash
echo "print(\"L\")while(0<1)print(\"ol\")" > lol.kts"
```

Then run it like this:

```bash
kotlinc -script lol.kts
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/@/oCgzr0RDyUdJszwjMydVw8DGUBMqlp@jpPn/PwA)

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to verify this on TIO; are you sure this works? The output is supposed to start with a capital L and print "olololol..."; this seems like it'd print "lollollollol..." (edit: testing with [this](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVD9vzwjMydVo6SoNFWzAChYoqGUk5@jpPm/9j8A) shows the behavior I expected)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino You're right this cannot be fully verified on TIO because it doesn't support Kotlin scripts. I missed the first capital L that, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Flipbit](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Flipbit), 24 bytes

```
<<^>>>^>^>>.^<^<^<^<<,^]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/38Ymzs7OLg4I7fTibCDQRicu9v9/AA)

or, using a bit less odd behavior:

```
^[>>>^>^>>.^<^<^<^<<,^<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/Py7azs4uDgjt9OJsINBGJ84m9v9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename only: 11 bytes.

Uses reference implementation feature: doesn't break the loop of .w and .a when stack is empty.

```
L.o.wol.p.a
```

OR

```
L.z.p12ol.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pTp7X@LIsv/zKXoiChGSgDqjI8ZZdNDhjIJH8c7sESe/SBqJQsKmg@KD@9X3VnV3njize/ayK0O6nl1VXV3V6Sebjf5ceWfcuJ7BRoXCCpnO6USf3Id0MtXp5Eaf@sydu2yiE9fTBr5DyRlgwENIg2lA4VsvrADdEbXDWUAZPBGNHPqTqR26N2NKHt1wRLx7vcQ4kedQh7ApHbpDdwAovscJDp5Cqs08NySDkR3YA@DLxzs@YWNQknh@QLzZeEyG8GPojqlnTyhHuQgDak80P3Ap8HdI2@hyjb4FbgjyyM2TTnpTmx7Zj8/UQ/2OXM8ek9nUsUOqk43aRl2vbeubdXLZO6x8RIwTd0A9BsBD4B26DxRnNPE9Rv5DA588AIGO1rqlITnrXrS/j58Im4FBXEbHlDFCvQc38L0JqFRggKTRWWE2sdk9qdW2t8kKzCeEnxsbDWIzPidh8wKdT/0gJCeHVvPkxDwshE9TimIGvjck@4ZDHwxuho39tTpZWxPwAShne85bcMnvrNn7YirFcoSpTWOmCAL0mFQtvuBQZXchfmgLJeJy2Wl/ty56n82NWm0TJoF6fznTLr/HYtAWJ79bh93z89Zhz6xLpOPO5Z8r5OyyR37vXp6Ts@@tU3IBvw5b5EvrvFU4ap@0Os3Tllk60X390R/rU90uFQ67nV6r0zPR1N2D3jeCCru3xPfIke9DjADTwYgO7l3vNgkKd1gghIAvvHBIVlm/7xGlGElQyCtCbwM6JdofRGuRPj7Dp1T@8Xr1o9@/Vvv9cu21hv/zv5pavvpR03auX4tqiRTCEfWQhA5GPumgreOQhQiP1SD1/bUNjjeHqK4Xhm7hn2tmvKaVe7/9WsM/@Eqpppayql3wdfMXGoH9/JkXgk7@bWBPCuisORKl9VKK0hFKajgeaxDHT0/rBpDmMBnyOCDaQAh1fI8WRKyKOF8K1ddX8oJcBLisluXc@eI5lA@OG4STKcTxS@/07HP7fBdjU4AGNqMgWGAoOINyqaRKYEJqwJccbDTKxhsIegJeXwaDaPFr1YhFNxqU2QP5wNMTtzaoUIxmUU4YuUNyRbSA8PnPAliM/oRcw1LF4UFuuEEil8YfHxZvk3hEC4mzRbQOga@HDFmCTseMZojLU4bUmk@mrlOloTuh1elgOqs@sGfwI@RDVUThW@JmXFIWHAbgHUZq9Y3Nrfcftnc@ktJV31u/LuXweFTreWLbHRPNI1sbOQCDNF5ixg99vV/W@y87/UVfLRr9upFnaz/eo062qW3Ut7a3djY/bO2QUgblxa6YxVpj0ep8fuEhSuxFCgMWgfiRTByZll4SFIZmLRdraiNFhi6G2DQV@2bg0OHtyL27H088f/pHwMLZw@P86bl5cPi5dXT8pf2vryenne7Zv88vepf/8@377/9JzGUpKaYnJizU23BUjrhnJPpB2TXrDXfPrNcabqWivmTmifA7gN8BfKtxB/AMOFmgbHbDwiCWUYXBMp@hun6iVutpmRERUdJqLuTP2IxqlALEZ5fsxyvRKHI5Cm5FeUWiBPgLTCgwZoFHatH6xzQiQxtTnCKyxS4ZQiRBzIQ@7GoeDSCOiU0Q5Ad28MQzoBKnv4RvHR/VwqJQGIyp7VmgBleiLGzLc49Gii91SDSk@KnAA96eklKJtL63e@TL5Rlpd3rk35fwcNY@a5Hmyfkp6bXOTxE3mBBtCBOM2CoxA@1v0fM8XayDfhEH3MLFnFVFbq0YrWwQuNOwwFlnZ/LXcgpQhZH9/ZSWZG@vBMn9qH1cKhy0jtsdbozLi5Z1cGjWeCAcnLeaX62TbvfM@val1bHanYvLo6P2YRt3a4HSPOie96yD8@5XgCMmxGYy3j45aR03T4Cw1zpunSNsURBCQSOoHsFj0gvpfaUuN8l0VqrHWWkpGWF8ZfJROg2tED@4tT33mZKxC5s3lISwLqCSEMCADvxbDn2wxy7G1j2UhIUk6Xzu9sytDyLbJGaCz5gBlbQC7kwT56pe37g28cdO7dpUpkoWVhew7Y8A83OwmoTtAMzLwmrvJWwTYG4G9hFAipUd@iiwP2wDaJCTIjntICeWg@1I2AeAPeQ0kLPaxlkNczA5qw84K5rjuSV5Ar0S5GBSzx3U8zEL25DW2EFrzHMwKW8H5T3lYFLPj6jnc9Ys21JNtJidU@WDZAnqKmFuelLNbVRzkoNJNT@gmk4GtoUWrmSHULKWGdpErHfZITR/MTuEolfjIRGP/Iln6CgcoUt7cP0ZM2WUX/H4vI7IotFKRYzjZlmISpVyTGwC@7W1Yg3LGhCe3nxw5@G0mrnR4D/Et6apy1vJUIkW26rT95Tq20rFGw/Os1iLxxfx7HA7T0qu8k/l/l2hi1KUFR5H7mBE/CHBPRy2HMpgL5nYIQxiL/tJYFH9ViePZD6f407jRz8fBRSKPFuQYp/Hiau8lCPMsI2mQbAHc2@hqaVkOAsAEghC5pMmmNjB3hiobwLMOsROpR2PsnD8YNZE4jF@XKGa10UjsgYXhoqCRwVu2qXcHA2PzsMkUIwfdkIOPpcSzFrayZxQaSoNvinVMg5Jk@0vUw0Ve3WAZk9UE7ialnZ4rFTGz/VG7BjbccjYvoGilj@LwfZpu9fstTvH5Ljb65ILeGidwi50Qb61oa896p6cdL8huPntK7notM/OWr1dQcrjpiHUXRFz4OxNyC3zuaK@wPciAmIp/WsMXdfTyBwGT73AlZWJj98elDBzl4XYsXJegmaRmpLruaFrj8dPUHaJEQgPKGjgb@Q/Ap/Q14BczoJHKYYT9POcKyxQiCcy9n0ojJhRNKpGDpMHHqImeIRj/iYx7Ud7/vhkC2zouYHvLIvPjOpv6wlrJLAjgpuA2vfL7DlBJKG5i8bAjX5MQwpTddzhEGYJS17WeLLjlytAsMGpgwUf0R7Rkkjtv8I3irLg5yvCvBBWFI@cxLER1OZkagehiKy3F5CIzUolikWol8uQeav4H2epZhYTUYQcRcjLLKu3WWtahjXaBXj/9ve5xysCTIH1pMfGWPHKsx2GlrWn0NEDBxwHg7JC1FUJzQTTWC9mGIt8gBsxrGhApEePN6n5RUk1zWc6Y6NymlZdpoTOblo0IM9CjfcOatnwqayq01mI5yjlqQ/dvyACPL9ogE5/geQtIeFJ4y3N47lFoR6efCGXBGIlkIg0AQ7y7AExzDBmOQwERrCHogF7KA0YTcaGRSPVzuECg8C3@A6GjR2XIEev3OuYjBYNiJjAx/mluAVv6Jdq6oQNYuwoJtHVsKgskOOUlTVFVd8IdB4U8XgcohEvu18W7LA9zzLs1yOOMr7fYpoP/Yhvs2jItfxJacj8QyNgmJ1u6I@oPc15esJxOEAaZBj4E/kcITlFg6eq2DKVd8VVTZgGfVFW980N1Q5gw5pAXAy4lThyvACBowOu5WlvyE8k@Uorx4dwJV4cybyEm01qhcGq4ssRtvoEn2sUL8alJkq1b/wgtNDQgo8qunDexL6kxM68AR6uQzngehLzhYX24P7KdUyoT2tCtOi00qd9CY9FzCQVdZxVlcWbPDOFqRqCeaXiOsC8kD6zqEGQMx7YqcIAfRLpo9WrEOU5haLjxUSfWJRDcdMgFvoTybXr/05ehcsDwy2yjS8/DoVuODXU4E14oQDbFeRucUoZn5GWSqQ0cvXpnJZIU4f/iE/0x@c75ut3@lx/1h91m@hzoj8R@576ugMDjk51OzovEYcYxbmSnfo8nrQ4OF38pEk/uuwc9trdzkWpELuKx0d5wm5TzTOBx1cFWeARiGgYxBkwdt0w6cgw18RlBI2cGgNTkZHNCOT6CauSGpQeDp1TJ0KBCPPc6Wws3uXEesjl@SJPWmIJUFYuEizh0CWkFAZ3nOUmwVuNsSqVa9Ny07iYA/LMqpoWU6QZh28ix6haPY0cZXDLrVp3wrIYaxYGmwXRFlEZG/CYOpqz7syYteXG1W56zHxLtvYWcg5uWney2OA@xMUA/0xmEKZygTxiwyFmyF@QQApMLeVkdiIvRrZwHYxtvrhSFkjyZ4QXLb@sUTkO@isGcx@BZq4PX3eoHuNv7Hityss5GLfH0Plw4M0TaM7oHzPqDaiE3sywiXq6oeK9oz3gr@SAGN9uzPC9YzpgxOaOOqSOj5Q@fFZ9bEMst5AJsHjLR@8OBBXkXvBr0stEXLfeqw1s06CEjlzsrptaPSn7eFwMYGe3BnvReS7oAo@puIjYybNYLrhaVytbO5y9zdiM26d5cdhuR06OVY7qFyuIleV9uTXzAHQzGybxF5jx4FXSRkcJ9A1Q5NwgmRGwx8JoDDED4@oeNIZZZDn9FGlKWS4j9khaZHbxuoxN7QHlWJJT@eMe4KytWXjmvaW@vsJ6Mzc3Fjxebn2@MROGp5yQn4Sfy8qqo1TXwN6AlLFY7GT0XRUtHiQLuYFLOSkL34FH19ZSGjWiGfOJchamPBPnkWKaW5tCPQiQVCstRyKK5JQnLS5jaZjr1s7r6/vtvSiAxfibx6apDU7kfUW3dvmRg@0ROWH4F6JNidsK3psmdCvEmXnQLLlD8N8tpPEA24fEaSqPdV7ghCMISUbwRbwfpjl0vzZ/JxBRLAvIeL6xfKi/3OyvEHwjxXs1x711Q15MYQyjDo3YWVs7SVy8325kXJeO/AAaaALCNVxWsZBltTKBy1@Jeo6LcWOPcxtruvCKll5Uzn1SIndEvrB3yQSCCBey/liFSgD@nqpoQP1ZOiT1hi6iUog1tlnI62iipFjYSJNaMUm1zb@rFu9vqxaj@Cj0S1iZ/DsOWT6EB6zpIItq6iVfvfvVgX8udfBd@J08/14UciEX19Z7G/9QjJimycXEY2LO2cHUNOeKGnuZk@9Jijdwn/K4@z/Hfc7jvjPTyHJrfhw9EZfYE9jD5LmIi2eKkSN3@dnUCJbYmDIydicuXmOB7u2W4jGkXMesCpwom9KBOBuCfH8UUHpw8blBavPtI/HBAg6PXSb2nPAGG2A7NfFBGOwq0V0KFOrywwIhmkB9OKYQLuSk2znmy546iXR5LgoU@ybZ3CA3sDzxqsxp8/eDFmxUX/EN0fkF6XXJ59Zh@3OLgAd7X1rnOAIgcnCYWkxJU2X5U56N76rWfbymxMumZDG70rNQTy252N2LSjKJfA/JAZMC1EeAb93nzyoBxKLdglfgq6yvrA7gj5FXfInU77/r94vwz7oBAzcDhSuIet4lEXdngmgAxzvjfUaruzdyM6xsf4pLOpm@fHOZpGdR796rP109wMLEVwgqiRt9bpKK7PMbedR3S6jrP0PVlMzhbYZIyxEJOl5F79VyB/1ZaVo9oVpkRP6vclVcvc4I/amrI2@vA8DMCVwy8DMNfM1xH1wG0aYs8chFzK@CJqVzembCXkXlk@Ua1t2u5a4CSzW3oy0KcYf2kw6u3Wn3SoXOuWnWX5JrBhaUx44lD4CgksST8QVg7ZsbsOmlgdF6MajnDAw1eQcATb@aPqpfiA5THClVKukjJ/56QBy@LwqoEHa7Jf8mBCaE@bNgAO0tb3zLu9hAbqrp22LydX2ubeZ4QPTGdaeX2srKurEgm/t45IDpR4qK3tw78nW2fGHPM@gQb@yNnwpl@ZZEHG1BmwB96P/rTk3uNs2DuFCTv02T2qX/mxs0P70789cvqpevzLxxWeatazLZWzK/vB8jbsYsX4wRV2LE7QJ9mH8FH18F@4cv4uNzDwxZKUh4N7qEJirWf8hdxZQsLcc7qZjJxL0dQXtJbyHW@KVUXt0XuIkytzQ4IQQ0Xz8QfNAugz5ojokd4i0/NIzoYbGplTY@xbsZ0Z3K5vmxddr8nl4or6981lu1jx9UhUQ3K04Ns/4e31eMbP6SaOI77vCJS5jbAVTbooMsyEaSEcgP@6fSX6zB8G1H4YWZCFgUElcy/pJAsNDa5Dly4fOf/wc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash (pure bash)](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html), <strike>43</strike> <strike>34</strike> 31 bytes

```bash
printf L;for((;;)){ printf ol;}
```

Thanks [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

Comment: `printf` is shorter than `echo -n`. `:` is shorter than `true`. No need for the single quotes.

Comment: If not done yet, take a look at [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash). Using those advices you may reduce this to `printf L;for((;;)){ printf ol;}`.

Answer (score 3):

### C# (<s>50, 45,</s> 42 bytes)

```
for(var a="L";;)Console.Write(a+(a="ol"));
```

It works by setting a variable to `L`, printing that variable, then setting its value to `ol`; infinitely repeating steps 2 and 3.

<sub>***Note**: Thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) and [@Browncat Programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857/browncat-programs) for pointing out a shorter alternatives in the comments.*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

*-2 thanks to [SuperJedi224](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39022/superjedi224)*

```
L::=~L
()::=(ol)
ol::=~ol
::=
(L)
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ao6egwh9/3/) is a Thue interpreter that works for this challenge. Paste the code into the box, click Update, and then click Step repeatedly (note that clicking the Run button will lock up your web browser).

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/38fKyrbOh0tDE0hr5OdocuXngETyc7iAFJdGvg9Q6P9/AA) has a Thue interpreter, but it adds a newline after each print and therefore doesn't match the output format of this challenge.

#### Explanation

The program consists of an *initial string* `(L)` and three *rules* for transforming it. The rules are applied non-deterministically: any time a rule can be applied to the current string, it may be applied. To achieve predictable behavior, we need to design the string and the rules such that only one of them can be applied at any given point.

Thus, when the string is in its initial state `(L)`, the only rule that applies is the first one:

```
L::=~L
```

This means "delete `L` from the string and output `L`."

Now the string looks like `()`, and the second rule applies:

```
()::=(ol)
```

This means "replace `()` in the string with `(ol)`."

The string is now `(ol)`, at which point the third rule applies:

```
ol::=~ol
```

This means "delete `ol` from the string and output `ol`." Now the string is `()` again, rule 2 applies again, and we continue ad infinitum.

Comment: Consider removing the lowercase ol from the last line, save two bytes

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Ah, of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Piet](https://github.com/cincodenada/bertnase_npiet), 48 codels

*Thanks @Bubbler for helping me golf my code from 66 to 48 codels by suggesting a 2 row layout instead of the 3 row layout that I initially used.*

Answered as part of the current Piet LYAL event. Tell me if there are any golfs, I just started using Piet :P

Original code

[image]

Enlarged version
[image]

You can test the code on [npiet online](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/npiet-execute.php) by downloading either image (npiet will auto-detect the size of each codel) and uploading the image file onto there.

You can also test the same code using its Ascii Piet encoding.

#### [Ascii Piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 48 bytes

```
tttliamtqimqqijsqrfeeeuLtt ii    qqqqi     fabsU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltc9u4Ef7OX4HSMxcqlmnJufO0nigdx1ESTx3bYyfNTF0PBxQhCbYI0iDol/aufz3dBUgKIBXJaaoPCQkuFs@@78IxLebfJlSR16/Ji/HZ@xfkDaHFhPOdnDMV5k/e1p92y0Luxlzs5k9qnolXnsfTPJOKFE9Fn/CsT6ic5VQWzJvKLCXnxyekojhO6Yx53scv4@jT4eXfyIgM4uFw6L09OTwyb4PBAN6@jKuXoffhYjw@NW/DgXcxfmc2AdnXj8efxw0L7@T4w8fPp@PLS5s1snt3eNHwhtfTs4tPhyc1R1jQG2uu8A4U0fjsxGJjNnoJmxImJlnCIsEeFlywItDKiVA5vQOPwM8s6I@wefk5LPIFV2ZTT1MaVklDe3Wtl6eZJLhEuLCZGe7441P9fbmAvy3yuZSCqDkjyHVBwIb4wkRCMoBNJ/Oaq8oIVwUBEVsc2F3J7@mCCeV8WNBCRZM5lcgYcGYyCZDV1c7wureG8pcR@Y@lytZhx1ONL6XFLVFZdmug13uzUiHsXAJcGi8YkVTMWL/Fo5jzqQJhSEwnt0ay1g5nAyrOQfiavNpz1diVYntE9n91aGq7IQmoYzKXgbOlt5JaGzGkeQ4WMeo7AP2RbYed2SqZQlv6fniTcRE4HHrGDRO2wQ3xMXrgat7QAFTfbzxMg288DKkdBzOywY5/Cr/jaHMmGeg@KxeJeAHKZ4SKJ9Kcw0XleRo2uWey4JloMYkZoGBAyAsyLcVEAQmhSVLg3tQhnmRCcVEubdnyxaXiLPDGA4nlf20xDqtAUXMIFUAhMoVBUwWMjpUZgzjJaVGAGGous3I2bzEB5HP0s8RZX6H87ZGG1ZCxRcE2IVqFBj0D0NRR3OIgsh0Q1wpksExCaG0bYtzvmWhl0Cjyd1uRPXBa9AvPnHlhvBVNDvu1CAS5ESUpB3azpWdIlmb31emVk3cPD2WhJM8DPKLyduOkKos41g/L2ftGY1HB/8X66GlxVrDRewrKreJgi3yit@CtpTReCjmYSbroeCsXOaQcKpd@q1UMnyo2qNe41vgSAfjgmpLgVR5ZIVsaXKepqFAJkzLwDy@Pjo936oPPkS0v/D4BC9rc@sSPnxSUAr@3mlH75A5Bz2tCWJDabKmVPtvq6Uq7JvM8U9qv6ByN/iHmWfKzEj2/6GoPAodLAMMIqs9jgEpGit73Kq@9cc74bI5qWJrGptkk@9Q/l9lM0pSgx2KM/9sC9AeJn@oFc9Affr9TnvRv6gf2zpfOJhMURc@vzX1OE8zX0IAZFenwLHI6gecgXqD1qy0rtHmFD@HipixUYB0Jzkj87@rMtDKG6Q@0NnZl6vY4a/M@/uYlIyM7/deNptuloJLg2MKldfvHduOgWY@I6TkBZfWuG9duC7FFvs4hknT2NfpNMiyVkyxlRjaAsJtQeUvuqeRUtDJ5G6bpWTvNzJJiRLDL7QIB32Oi4IprUwaDPhn@Za/VoCzarMxpz2G299tvm5hptW7kBahWcOOFhHw4InGWLQLU@C8EBoA2zUwyyGYOlR4a2nTxQruHRYaDhkslZzHCsdBdaRDXK@PQJdM4nkOIQFqds4mUuj0EFHXSmQEcPTWFkDED/@LDW6gLbhzasd9r9oVQzxKqaGBH9ha5nEBfYCoebiNljkmHkimdKHBr6Bwg@0MhWNbVZ2b1D0xA5VBY7w1nnWRMQ4NsfLtWr03mktFFk6HtfP2yjUpTNinZydAdWqNKVIxkuBgEy3P6NqcevhU0zRdsZDR/Oj68GF9@dppzYGR6k1wXMNj7GIgy7RPNcDSo2g9YjmAZTq4Ield7B9e1So1Yb8hgqVRnAz6FUmfeOucOfAdGRWSgPD4mgW4QoH8SsyWCpEzzZffPcabVTw9zDr7AYQzCatbZae@GhtASlPfJn3UXeED8hjReZJDnIL4aPlf8gG8P969tbmgVaxSpk/4NZkU9sekctQ/JoOcmjWbv9qiZjCxIMe7QrGJkpcFc3RzcbO9da6QWUEummmlV3n4d9FZRwWZkUR2KjXHcQ/O92iOvQV78Z7i3r1t64of@6ortVG8H5uoz6wbbmAxWhvstwyNp3SxXjXKeYZK5ZxEEVeAYE8YBdP/lchPW8AEEsFwQ2nYQ5O8UstRYygxiOwXlmDFPZ7IZkwSSHYVWEWcVQVpOCSwrOHZwv6RyVtTTKX4wK30yBS8cFU9FaAhBFA9wRZGgKYsiPYVGUUq5iKJqFq3vl3D8rp/DQzkrUxh5zvWXujGsKUNwlYhWJIG/g@21v7NTZSYAS8uFGg37RD3lbGTrsb/OnnO2yEf@Wan09CDs1Ic5dgY8hJME1zFLmaLQDoz8o7N345Po8vgfY3@DGI9GDIh8eKB6ih75BWRyFilZbjjPBV9g/mhckItCMaqHT0kfTFBvAnNvwFSF4mcBsUcYIAEHBEtKzfVAjNdCqFc9Iq0NND@vGm2oZcavNqCHg8APAbRArxz5f7Xc4jQT7BnAL7NSTpj2Zx3i7lhnJsz1oIPqxAMsSAnR16eAnoveBvSgmJ@G/w7SNhdG1Y0M56cf8DLuR6Br/zFqh5018ixHxoUVsTLU/6EUzXQ2renCDe3GUSaAQrcbWksrRmiAAOh952qo5m6sXV/7oILcauMeZhn2APTqMumtudP5PhvyWtv1zWp4lTmfi69tORtkxer5KDvMNFRg88Zf27Y9U7tKPrmn62SZQd8btPSKKWnanRyc24hpiIESWNI9Tliu1sl3hPeWGlgTY2ts2hREr6s7fYktMlKJ@wB4Ievcc/DAfjuAvZXwq6rHhS2G6VTX3HnVWN1br1bgdIwC2d2G/k5HaTMHQDOC6d8kW2JuvkiRswmfcggokwJWuWonTrsaNwldxyqmE60s0FVVaiyvqlpHRrH/5Vn4Ft@PzyzzYv9e0HsWLEmh5rhhvux4rYYYCMMZU/fY1QS9/y3oup5abemTFw8vvuev0/BBcsWCCtbGQHQJXaL/i97b9fxH1QBDJFjA8h3gSfUJldvUQaBPdIfw2nwdBbZsuOp63ARbE2q6t@qbaoMiGSw48i6Lz@rDq6iD72FcTqdMNsePz957k3maJWT7sfV3T8/5q@jvJNx1vsMUh087WH/CXMy@KaUWnKbqjqd3d/ymuJNTxlh5ohThHOHcwY8bD6Fx8eUbnu3tgmJ2kdGu0CnC5flf)

#### Explanation

```
PUSH 5            [5]
DUP               [5,5]
PUSH 3            [3,5,5]
MULTIPLY          [15,5]
MULTIPLY          [75]
DUP               [75,75]
PUSH 1            [1,75,75]
ADD               [76,75]
OUT(CHAR)         [75]       (prints L)
PUSH 6            [6,75]
DUP               [6,6,75]
MULTIPLY          [36,75]
ADD               [111]
DUP               [111,111]
OUT(CHAR)         [111]      (prints o)

(Start of two-row infinite loop)
DUP               [111,111]
PUSH 3            [3,111,111]
SUBTRACT          [108,111]
OUT(CHAR)         [111]      (prints l)
DUP               [111,111]
OUT(CHAR)         [111]      (prints o)
DIVIDE            [111]      (stack only has one number, instruction ignored)
GREATER           [111]      (stack only has one number, instruction ignored)
```

Even though the last two instructions don't seem to do anything, they actually act to convert the code back to the right color without affecting the functionality of the code. Because Piet instructions are entirely based on changes between the colors' hue and lightness, we need the color before the Dark Magenta color block in the infinite loop (e.g.: the color right under it) to be Dark Yellow, or else the Dark Magenta would correctly act as `DUP` the first time around (when entering the loop from the right), but be a different instruction in subsequent iterations of the loop, messing up the entire code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 14 bytes

```
;O'L\'W1O'ol\'
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLSeS4Kq2bGSKZCFFHYEsJJcP2BeELGPVyrJPkmE5wv31XHfPi0a2yV3ulg@WNfN0T/czPd09JurdRdH3V0kWpatJfFCUk2TxejZsmiNpclsbisrHZbwGypPsrjZUJnOBmcTTJItZmrJ0kd3RR1OPfjr//IF51evVp0vmV69/O7pk@9Xryfk79kv1evmZeRX45OzKwJ5/PjOgn88/HF391S44s/Gjzf7l/YXr2aMrWFZMRrMwZx1eCZgosFWrGA7ZfjV3fvwFJzOYJI@@Mfx@cLCGwWUIg24CJk05AmuYtxcXZwTCj0Nyso@@GYZcvhcAkDdsvQ/TVcz5dTbmzSb5AbtyPQ4uW8cXJ/b3wYV1NrK@eBfWIh1Z3zkMtgYC1wFgHM5ZgBKDZhPULsO8iG3OnpqNJCtZMmg2YJSWcFhnusoiGCHhCN7L@dIpltm1Pw6eXMd9Bh2NBNQRHp4uDrx5g@qTJXuYJWVcLMMobjbgexrbMA7itjDDYa1ROcpG01HOnp6vxzbvv2pxMqWRTJmtrQ2Y9criTKhQozswOspguNsVI2BnI06L2Bx4FuZEszj6nU0XOctW89s4L6Q9zE6KSXKXlEorrI7ueI72SDw7zHNZl3Wk5d0uZz1muRYsgZYmnOVxucozpoJCiFFcDNZtuA/zJLxNY2UFGJEuHuLcjmA9ZQj79o0p4yJ6i4iIrxaX9CRbXE8Cz4E9CvTwmnV4zGQ4AiSbrJY2bimTnPYYvG0aLA59IbQJM0aWVdnUssSmgTB4oI1ioASSBHwHy5ZhUbJyFoOyMC8BLDegoxjFDY04eqKMNc7Oi8bCp8dpoxsVGWQ@hm6ZLDIwGyPWHYNpkWKkWC2XSDhXUaVGTPrN@APaDbJRhwrlZQZxDAkLI1daLlj5ZOlTLQZOcACTVx@TFpqpgozynXDVRrvR1DBNF5G97zoeRwdxWDtBDmarNA3zR9PRan8uje35aGnLaEEpv8rWpGkJD5eQSWGbp0fHb9/d/LZz9uuF4bCp9jbZqtff1LtTU/z@9OoFjWWck8owm7B/rEL1imrvzSX2NpcQBLy3NBenW7gg4f26cB3zTKkyX2W4QwOZdDvlorBVrqQDAKFdJhGj2dvV9NrfH0s7xEa3KT1oA4olHKtyagMU/N9N00lL5R0qOg4qWVcAh0IrEOVMrF/DHTBvr@4nOo@xeMhaZb6KWxCDehxDEsanIWQQnGhhZLUqEtBP9F3WHaLj69vFIoWZ2zoDL/paufUjhzo/75Fp5u2GmSnamP2pNkLQlos0tU1THeY6UCH@B5OzDZOxCn84@njuYC0WgQavp9ee67oQTuAKvKq3Ivln/LVk@BgYMWp4iwzAm4MfPn3uBZ4q6ZjhsKrjgz598dgDwMnp2XGHTSE5Dho6tOV6mIajcOmkcUYdgMGVaosEZ3DuXiJjXRBrE5Y2LDh2Qr0E1OID4mIARSXBSZ03ovlybQeIpGRcpRCkKRnjMsVDUkYzuwPMbHRRwBGTfxHWKevI6jNcRQACJBT7MMjCvE1OSfWyE6yFLB9QFa4Q1G6WOZYu6jivx/ypCjNooCi3i4UvYeG67hwyns3b7h9T/KuQHwEJWgVHd3GZQrNot2kv27hDWCInScYHydS2aT@xIYhmOdriQJxyLrY5cAdbbYUHpzZArHcs1hOdI2YDSchA2YskydxZWfm28kfg9cy7agYlTYo15gYwGA0Qf8FysYwz21jYaeUtahXAqmAuKiXEY@C7@7/QuGwubNGRTMH0CToFLRyErIP9HcChd6A3XAOWVuFlwyDrBtQK4YkFJJd0gx5ai6hGDZ2A@WbPUtFYefIbeBL/AW0cnvYNP3dqu053gh3MZBvAs43wgFXSOi8G/FerL/vELYGsM5@sQK1zaottrEFcFaHhcJ9XjeVGOlSiV9Qc2rsFCtYPw6Yw0Amtj7kuZFLeqqBqAstLHGZS7UslTNYscwdkbpEsXFQs4MEQFx8kTexnjTrWbtNFqtdD6Fi0uSNqtxvKrN3XnQLsseGNM3XUcsP8VVmo3dcxIXo9YVBXG0R5EvIlpmQMLWN7RDfdqO@2uJUiGvp@pmLJF3uO/S8dBrEBhMJhPOWB8tLn20M1Ckv1kF2n161o4uo76uLQjTr0LGWOkH71NqLTiHZs1ev2CqFOtTtbWFgvz1t46GzwIPZ1GwvzLa51CBOYSkgAapBNGTKwRnDJQ9Cg1yN9kigqmesbLRgta6f/zQ@JebOdmN0fCu1uF/o7sVlzSFwdaMw3vRxI2gXrAet5mmXCAvUenLOeB2fMM8H@T6IPID3WsEGAUFq3r0ZcRTkR7Q9dybXPqV3pBMR/c/1A0CS5AncESrBYYuA7XhlmcR5bBcsW0EMnaZlk7CF8BN7YZAF30jK@i3OQWS6yOCuTEG8RcJIX7CFms/A@BqBUhPCSzcNsBeHz@BpH0btbZByoICaKVVrijwa0uE54CtIzMWrJNcpMOQ1ZU4/6Xka6LxuiYQc1lEv38zDF2vgIXmeTNJ6wm8rsG63lCb@JxsxYpHJmiMp6PfXOCd6Q0I5h@rPOgwcUrGuFD5NeLS8G9ax4yMzDf2AeAxTty9/b2kwADlmtUaRBhxnZEHW4QlKVXF/UAcTuBFBtjC5oCIcSQ2sxWfTZPJ5HSwyzjA1vDv9fV4Z/gitD5crOFl8C6Yt05fBl9sWqW0zG6UNWA/ga4asCurPNzupFu6cyj6lAm9eu0h/6sq02HJqSMpVo@W//jbzMQYYaLT@w@ia61uauY4Mq69anf/oio3rb6iaDuEbtNqNTIWFQ4zioSRtpEiUQ0e1qMWHyF3BP/OplNpo175jZu0ix03rXjlBD/tDv7xm0vBdXhsDosLpmAdq8I2Xy4uHos7BXa2ivBNFrSgfrJc/fVvL2uO4DfC29T4P/oSFCw/CJWxHp5l@3Q2Zv5IOHuGrXwyaJGgQR/2KSHoToypMAq0/iaQhJEjxTHWaSwWQyoR@RwqiEMmXtRhb2nDjC2Qu3WFSmayB0g/KHhHmYZNissjC/ixxS2unA93uOP1fR/RL/fWO7ZE39Gvf8/d8)

My first Knight answer :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 13 bytes

```
"Loo,l",..o"v
```

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%22Loo%2Cl%22%2C..o%22v)!

The `L` serves both as a literal character and to redirect the IP.

Unfolds to this:

```
    "
   L o
  o , l
 " , . .
o " v . .
```

Instructions are, in order:

- `"L`: Push 'L' to the stack
- `o`: Print character
- `"o`: Push 'o' to the stack
- `o`: Print character
- `,,`: Pop twice (to keep memory bounded)
- `"l`: Push 'l' to the stack
- `.`: No-op
- `vL`: Redirect the IP, closing the loop. `|` would work as well as `v` here.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes

```
ûLoÉ_q!↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wbp/8w53xhYqP2ib@/w8A)

I'm fairly new to this language, so this can probably be golfed.

## Explanation

```
ûLo      # push the length two string "Lo"
   É   ↑ # while true, execute these three instructions:
    _    # duplicate
     q   # print without newline
      !  # lowercase
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 11 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy

```
OoUª'L
ß"ol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3z8/9NAqdR@uw/OV8nP@/wcA)

### Explanation

```
OoUª'L    // Output input if it exists else 'L'
ß"ol      // Run program with input being "ol"
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3z8/9NAqdR@uw/OV8nP@/wcA)

Comment: Or [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/38E/PyczvzbRP1/d5/9/AA) if you want to avoid the overflow.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
print('L',end='')
while 1:print('ol',end='')
```

How it works: The program first prints 'L' and then infinitely prints 'ol' on a single line using the `end=''`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ91HXSc1L8VWXV2TqzwjMydVwdAKKpOfA5f6/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>7</s></sup> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
║►yü[c
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ba1079815b63&i=)

### Explanation

```
.Lo{cpvW
.Lo      push two letter string "Lo"
   {   W loop forever
    c    duplicate           → ["Lo", "Lo"]
     p   print and pop       → ["Lo"]
      v  lowercase           → ["lo"]
         begin next iteration
```

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell v5 32 Byte

```
while(1-ne2){Write-Host -n 'lo'}
```

Has someone an idea how to shorten Write-Host? Is there an alias?

**New One 52 Byte**

```
for(1){Write-Host -n 'L'
for(1){Write-Host -n 'ol'}}
```

Comment: The first character printed must be a capital `L`, the rest must be in lower-case. You can maybe answer [Scream verly loudly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200306/scream-very-loudly?noredirect=1&lq=1) like this.

Comment: ...although actually there already a terser [Powershell program there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200549/53748).

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You can shorten your answer by 4 characters by removing the not equal expression: while(1){Write-Host -n 'lo'}

Comment: This is close, but does not write to a single line: while(1){('L')+('ol'*100)}

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vzgxR6FcIbwosyRV1yO/uISrXEE3T8GHKy2/SEOzGszJz6n9/x8A "PowerShell – Try It Online") with `set-alias`. [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P7wosyRV1yO/uERBN0/Bhystv0hDsxpVND@n9v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online") with raw powershell

Comment: There is an alias for `write-output` called `write`. That should drop a few... but it does it with a new line.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```r
cat('L');repeat cat('ol')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPdR13Tuii1IDWxRAHMz89R1/z//z8A)

Well, this one is pretty straightforward.

*−1 byte thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

Comment: Shaved off a byte. https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPdR13Tuii1IDWxRAHMz89R1/z//z8A

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 10 bytes

```
76;["ol":]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0?code=76%3B%5B%22ol%22%3A%5D&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```scala
print("L")
while(1>0)print("ol")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQ/b@gKDOvREPJR0mTqzwjMydVw9DOQBMqmJ@jpPm/9j8A)

- -1 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!

Comment: `1>0` is one byte shorter than `true`.

Answer (score 2):

### [SABDT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Sabdt), 23 bytes

```
pr"L";wh(0=0){pr"ol";}
```

Exspanded:

```
pr "L";
wh(0 = 0){
   pr "ol";
}
```

the 1st line prints "L".

the 2nd line is a while loop. 0 is a variable reference, since it has not been declared yet it starts as "", an empty string. essentially it is a while true loop.

the 3rd line prints "ol".

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you mind providing a link to this language, so that others can check/verify your solution?

Comment: @caird-coinheringaahing sure thing

Answer (score 2):

## BRASCA, <s><sup>14 12</sup></s> 11 bytes

-1 bytes from RezNesX

```
`loL`o[:mo]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwK1r5VUS7acR5P4LLd2kl7dJnHGdud643EZSIQkpiTBkKBlTx9fPbcLPkSQkAjGT8@0sUlg97dPLIBlcCVm3H/8PAg/O17AQ0Giq6hHPCpmrUnIPSIcj5HslctYkDwOqW/DP@kL/Av@m7JW@kCEdMxGdPxHqzV2aRSRg5BGY/oSf99pEfhZW1s7ETCgR0I2dSLBwogAFXJBQ4eOXBbBADnQZhNiWY7vCMvqRMyddHda8gX@rEsacmJOJn@JgzcjOWBIzs7V5xSeDdRHI@XRgsd@yMicAQNqO/6UsAsWgtbwVxqR8YyCrMj3@zLjEIZYHrcZ0P2RuhEr4H7vBMzuOz6xqaD5Y2dCfC5NANOB2aYTUSGuOt2dfEiBPgywcDqQX8xAlJ3u2c5Of/tcmTThIbF6xCLAlPmxx0IqWKdEqsRIwwztFcWuQKbqmzNk2as8LeNQLbNJg4D5doeHdich3O3mwxnorE5y8JKFVn@i6ESpcUaM@SQAIwhmkysmSvahLqrqyspGVG10OnMiMndcl0SCgw9Q@E3MGBmBwf9gggQ8coTD/ZLHzWeOyyyX8yACon/@rVBkZIwOgQ6LpAKOzEOVAI6w0jdVLx0nDlWUWz6HyHOdMUQJ2DYXRj9C8EAVd/19HM0ITBwBR8ElNGmePAIDGGAlA6TP9HB0wVuqFsX3ReoX1I0Z4ZNFxCAnDRd8n/LAX1cyQbeRg7rLBRlxISBVAeeVYlnJuDrpHD9ioegMkiH1AhohwBkq/@WSLwBUhQe7yuxcYsGDLHGWE01OVg2zkIk49AueV43EdEgBGLJJYreEplYFPCgKfwcwB5nGTiCMEVC2eOSYIias7GFqkuxPFV/2lAwhJumaJl3RLFUuFJRgLc8e6WaPqrMLPlfE3o5SF9QGMCa7m5JICcFExq5e7kFTcaukR129UgapCY9xPY6YVmT5puxUBT7ZiG5OS3oLknKZPxUzvcMm78p0U1eDl50Fi0Joxi4suJKaXCEIrhDEBX2QTnnd6OasRrHj2snDMj/BvEAtbPCJBXWHUnOoL2FhdNmnmAumWAeLg2w5g@TDPQ9XqGqlgItPqUYAs1ZI75FBtZCojOoPybYySvpIFedwObWSrGVgmSDobmdryaqrzEsn6slnbpgpplsFW2Rw3ogBeEeIRZRkpGaGZdXEmZxzDpMyRPVTspE4S05fLUN7rVbTp2HM6m07JI9Wc/rQ2BzFYRUQpvRxYj351JtauAc5uYKM5REaTiESfAHbl0DumbAMhC3NZnBFJmR3Air3qcf2qm/HZBfDZq/VOuUQT7i5gdAexdMeiSFvTeytMYYacKE25pvJ1ngTh0YunxObz33CYxHEIh0ebY0jCczBfRHytCwpsWV5FOpiKzVhAgAMUdh6pU6WYssrybXPH1z@5gM/2/H4@ed0d5bkLXKACSjJiJivPBoUSRTTU5bqyFuAIUfLv5NkV2CZl7a7MlcW3hSTW3ilmim3bZHUmYbseTkJpGOU/dhSR6s8WCdyod2FPLinFqwrcs1AE0YFrRWL6UE17iu@vG1ObtuA3CNzco8MyD02J/fYgNwTc3JPDMg9NSf31IDcd@bkvjMg98yc3DMDcs/NyT03IPfCnNwLA3JuAzc2CYs3DeiZeB5rEBcmxn3dIDBMAs1uEBkm5n3VwJdNYmPWwF1MvPmnJv5i4jC/NCJoQvHPtR2y/oqNQ4a1gSnx7BFWfX2TjP03sjn0r8Fmw4RNiGzkcncsD3N1fOhiBdZXrRKMySDcczi4x5Anx51Rj1BAqbfQEgmdbqu6YEsBktUeaqUZDWsFb39or3QM9ShXWwAbVdJlKeRJV005s7F93l1FSKmoNnBHVdXIW4o72QD3cbxwPr4U@wb6wb5t37ID6Fx2gxr4aR/xncQjvGUQ9wCybwLyWwT5NnaFE7hX9wDyWxOQW0liEWwK3mM7F06k21XePtitLRO0X0uVcjt2@T1g/NoE4u8I8fVlwP1lifqWrW5k9kgG0KfwOgirzPHScHMCG7/01wgYdGi3q0vSB46YO7CdbZCV/kHQ745ObxTzPybq@kbmw3ev7sGe35jg@wvxHR3fA7y/TOBZCO@3e8H3O@DTeN@JdhNfAU4ReCDP2fni7Hp/ZalQvDcAAgbqGWm5HJhzGZlw2ZdcsisZM2HUOwMzaQ70fA4a8DGSp4d80vP7JYcyCofsoL@W8A4StmO8KpXn9SAKn6zg8KWZh15nZAX1v1XUi@s2U@DZDZwpqmw8vYEJFWk8lMbjF6r6MT4SIlqWyeXXFxkjwyZJGOB7m@MrKVrevaUHn/X4murcGF9Qoz/iy76eSO8XHo99YbqD8xc7uEEvmbpiD2dso5ux0/saOz0gPaz2hWv6w/cyWSYtW2lzxKC//eiZqd/l/V0d2GeWzxW6BgC@yte4xb1qbdLWnGWkN68mLP@FLKM5DaShxZwTRzAvIty/djK/9Yw/MpDvWNqUi2yRErOQsbuVcXzrihhfR2Xa@5yKHk9Qj2Pu47rp58oEd0kIR3fvJxhjkUCRNvAfahRh07IYyx0gbRxANu325kfu@JKd310ksvzgC1sYlie9MaY5SCaF1Fe40ktn15/oNVEOgjdQh5OqA8o@QYCI42DKT3Nfp687H1eE6qUpWmmBUORaLhZASSbvDcmT52lXK/69OyRPny2fp5w4AosziQRv7uV0AF0v92FR7kUfXKKBzsadyT1QxX7xxVID5Fa92Jey/HWASGjXl@wr/a5C@7cibZPC2mRRr3CJkcuvfv9ES9I3LUNk004Szc1O0iEZ2CZ55tcU53QpzmJOuUxyymUlp7Tq3EDtbLppMTVnAodbRwaOxuVRi@zHwO7v/ZOXh4dpl2Od1y1aESqtx0vbEUqiVHuWtZcR@COHdMYz9Rqo24OwtofttoGlj5aKahIE9y9tHnxNhPZVodMM@nANXDRuAzHfLRfzoRpXY9iFwJp4fsl9EXKX/Ojyeb1CdlEhb1gUQR1Nb/sGBNW3Sxslrm09JWai6qbtRnuoi/@AeWQL@92oY@/hqmMor3Q@xeDWd6CI4fDBaqL9vzZo4oCJOWP@Q9haor6wuhzj/x6uA/2ADnTKQs/BjVnrZpIifvHFLh1hUluuIwDIh7ZsBaYu@Rh7QU1il1pHvQ5q9VFtQahF9BER/QwosJqbQ2EdNelxUPtn6rn9nHPDTxKbseur7DYM2J0hu/9i22tf9sxW@66r6k5q3q@w6F25wVJ2Sv3t8xoLLZMqF6rYK17bTKuV9rwkLSzJtyXr3q2KauJJL1d39ZS@wTPrFDo1pJl8tSdpttSdS/KNipQiCJk8kInyz1Xxk8i0HaraMa/vjdY3ya@f4uctjoDScELmM@bDFp8D41BGlXDApsB2Art3u6Y/ulm/lfoZS47mCFnLHgJ5ruyIlnkyrzRhpeBKnQrrb@UVSvbRZvljTaMUyC7HLBDkF3Y14pB4sNcmDONAlL59qmbzdOJr@Q@kbTRkSZz1E@6x5GPXOfMFmYfcn/bwJJjPwTgEOHEVblJKr70@Pj463iG66aW712RC/jn3JqRrjwoLwJUP4QsiJN8BHKaOm36@0Gq6cViMVUIAfEyzw1h5z3uNo0o6XFmFaDBi6OsxVjertG7PtoS4PkAXtGmVrJZcqs8quRViNxa5Xtzmoi4VE38@/x8)

### Explanation

```
`loL`         - Push 'Lol' to the stack
     o        - Output the 'L'
      [:mo]   - Output the next character of ['o', 'l']
```

Comment: 11 bytes: `\`loL\`o[:mo]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Fueue](https://github.com/TryItOnline/fueue), 14 bytes

```
76):[111)108:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SytNLU39/9/cTNMq2tDQUNPQwMIq9v9/AA)

### Explanation

76 is the character code for `L`, 111 is the code for `o`, and 108 is the character code for `l`. This code first prints an `L` and then goes into an infinite loop that keeps printing out `ol`.

```
76):[111)108:]

76              Print 'L'.
  ):[        ]  Turn the stuff in the brackets into 111)108:[111)108:]
     111 108    Print 'ol'.
        )   :   Loop infinitely.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Turbo Assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler), <del>136</del> 119 bytes

```
.model small
.code
start:
mov dl,'L'
mov ah,2
int 21h
i:
mov dl,'o'
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl,'l'
int 21h
jmp i
end start
```

Ungolfed version:

```
.model small
.code
start:
    mov dl, 'L'         ; move "L" character to DL register
    mov ah, 02h         ; print "L" character
    int 21h             ; interrupt
infinity_loop:
    mov dl, 'o'         ; move "o" character to DL register
    mov ah, 02h         ; print characters
    int 21h             ; interrupt
    mov dl, 'l'         ; move "l" character to DL register
    int 21h             ; interrupt
    jmp infinity_loop   ; go to "infinity_loop" label
end start
```

-17 bytes thanks to [@Kamila Szewczyk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61379/kamila-szewczyk)

Lololololo[...] in action:

[image: Lololololo[...]]

Comment: Turbo assembler for which processor? I'm guessing Z80?

Comment: not yet, it's a x86

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/fish), 12 bytes

```
"L"v
l"o<o"o
```

#### Explanation

```
"L"v     // pushes the character 'L' onto the stack and moves to the second line
l"o<o"o  // after outputting the L character, enters an infinite loop of pushing "lo" and outputting both
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
LＷol＋］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=TCV1RkYzN29sJXVGRjBCJXVGRjNE,v=8)

Constructs an infinite length string.

Explanation:

```
LWol+] | Full program (characters replaced for clean spacing)
-------+------------------------------------------------------
L      | Push the string "L"
 W   ] | While ToS is truthy (without popping),
  ol   |  Push the string "ol"
    +  |  Add the two strings (i.e. append "ol" to the string)
       | Print ToS (implicit) (will not ever actually occur)
```

Non-empty strings are always truthy in Canvas.

Answer (score 2):

## [COMET II ("CASLシミュレータ （CASL II 対応）" by Daytime)](https://www.officedaytime.com/dcaslj/), 28 bytes.

The leftmost column shows an address, and one word is two bytes.

```
0000: 7001 0000 7002 0000
0004: 1210 0012 1220 0014
0008: F000 0002 7120 7110
000C: 1210 006C 1110 0012
0010: 6400 0000 004C 006F
0014: 0002
```

The simulator seems to output an LF automatically every time `OUT` is executed, and it requires you to set a break point to see how it works by step by step.

### Original CASL II assembly program (63 bytes)

```
A START
 OUT Z,=2
 LAD GR1,108
 ST GR1,Z
 JUMP A
Z DC 'Lo'
 END
```

### Usage example

Run just for a few steps, as I have no ideas how to scroll back the console.

[image: Run just for a few steps, as I have no ideas how to scroll back the console.]

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (ppencode-cpmpatible), 87 bytes

```perl
print q pop xor print chr ord q else while length or print uc chr ord q else and s qq q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpBCoAwDAXRq/xLeCBpgymENElb9PZREFy4nOEZhWyZFk0nHNYNVw@8XTjQoz6fZBBObkIQ0mMyPrTK3@1aMeAOz7wB)

### How it works

```perl
# NOTE: q x STR x eq ' STR '
# chr ord STR to obtain first character
   print q pop xor
   print chr ord q else
while
# default variable is initially empty string
   length or
      # print first L
      print uc chr ord q else and
      # make sure not to come here
      s qq q
```

Answer (score 2):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), <strike>51</strike> 49 bytes

```
P76
A0A0
A0C3G1G1A0
A0P111P108A0
A0A1G-3G-3A0
G-3
```

`P76` prints a 'L' (ascii code 76), after which the code enters an infinite loop. In this loop, the following code is executed.

```
P111 P108
P111      ; prints 'o' (ascii code 111)
     P108 ; prints 'l' (ascii code 108)
```

This prints "ol" infinitely, producing the rest of the infinite output.

Edit: It turns out that the loop does not have a required minimum of three instructions, which allows us to drop a no-op, saving two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```
"L"write [ "ol"write t ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQma@QnVqUl5qjYP1fyUepvCizJFUhWkEpPwfKLlGIVcjJzy/4/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
\L₴{‛ol₴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcXEzigrR74oCbb2zigrQiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Will add an explanation soon.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyI9IiwiIiwiXFxMe+KCtOKAm29sIiwiIiwiIl0=)

for 7 (6.375 w/ vyncode)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 22 bytes

```
until(!L=ol,print1(L))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/vzSvJDNHQ9HHNj9Hp6AoM6/EUMNHU/P/fwA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 22 bytes

```
while(!print1(L),L=ol)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/vzwjMydVQ7GgKDOvxFDDR1PHxzY/R/P/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 33 bytes

```bash
a propagate:
*=>ol/_ $
*=>L/$ _ o
```

Explanation:

```bash
a propagate: # while the input changed last iteration...
*=>ol/_ $    # append "lo" to the end of the input
*=>L/$ _ o   # prepend "L" exactly once
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

`(L)S((ol)S:^):^`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fw0czWEMjP0cz2CpO0yru/38A)

Prints out `L`, then `ololololololololol...`

## [GolFunc](https://esolangs.org/wiki/GolFunc), 13 bytes

No interpreter yet, but you can look at the specs.

```
..P'L.Y.P"ol"
```

Explanation:

```
 .P'L         # print L (returns identity, so no worries)
.             # apply the result to...
     .Y       # the Y combinator applied to...
       .P"ol" # the function which prints "ol"
```

Comment: It's Underload!!!!

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 8 bytes

```
"loL"o<o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xykn30cp3yb//38A)

Port of ovs's Befunge-98 answer.

##### Explanation

- The IP starts in the top-left going right.
- `"loL"` pushes the characters `"l"`, `"o"` and `"L"` to the stack
- `o` outputs the current character (`"L"`)
- `<` makes the IP go left
- `o` outputs the current character (`"o"`)
- `"Lol"` pushes the characters `"L"`, `"o"` and `"l"` to the stack
- `o` outputs the current character (`"l"`)
- (at which point we're back to `<`)

**Old 12-byter:**

```
"L"v
o"o>o"l
```

- The IP starts in the top-left going right.
- `"L"` pushes the character `"L"` to the stack
- `v` makes the IP go down
- `>` makes the IP go right
- `o` outputs the current character
- `"lo"` pushes the characters `"l"` and `"o"`
- (wraps around to the start of the line)
- `o` outputs the current character
- (at which point we're back to `>`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lean Mean Bean Machine](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/lmbm), 19 bytes

```
OOO
"""
Lol
U!!
 ~~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8lNyv3/39/fn0tJSYnLJz@HK1RRkUuhru7/fwA)

Lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + `jot`, 23 bytes

```sh
<<<L`jot -s '' -b ol 0`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsbGJyErv0RBt1hBXV1BN0khP0fBIOH/fwA). This times out on TIO (and crashes my Terminal app) because `jot` is busy printing millions of copies of `'ol'` to memory before `<<<` gets a chance to print it. According to the spec, that's an acceptable result (and it allows me to beat the bash solution!). However here's a [finite example](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsbGJyErv0RBt1hBXV1BN0khP0fB0tIy4f9/AA) that doesn't time out:

```sh
<<<L`jot -s '' -b ol 999`
```

Comment: otherwise, do `printf L;jot -s '' -b ol 0`

Answer (score 2):

## [Flip](https://github.com/jfioasd/Flip/), 10 bytes

Perfect challenge for showcasing Flip's execution model.

lang is not on ATO yet, so I'm using a makeshift one.

```
' L|qq'ol'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVpve9u2EX@vT4EqS03Fkmplz7MXWpItnePGq6tkTtZu81wFIiEJMQnQIGhLXbavnt0BlERSBE3Jif08cRIAvPvdXxwOiJd6LsXve/EyXn7mUSyVJskyaWX/jKiet1p@SJOEnIQ8HrYI/ARsSsZjLrgej72EhdMuiZWcdews/uBgH8fIczNVnOAxDB@Vx8aJZjjxtFWcSTT1r2D84rI0EUjBYPyEhgkrc@ZCs6B6kgvgpKrnkivAIbbRCbbQY39ON58V56nvw8zgD8VRqedMje1cb9Ba6@6KsTjTm0ijstpW8m7@c9GDZcPLDQHFbsaBodAZkkfknN0wlTBy@pYEXDFfcynWNPm0qOAX5Ai/OaE@FzOi@Gyu@@vFeRP1QKD1BAOZc5@FbOr46hC/cpm2VxjIyYMoxopNZCoKcpkBMlUysmuITHVPTntmvF/hVSET3tr5OsDQW4tTmsPJwa5AeTIG34pYpfVA0zBAnoMGhmAinSqR86OpVIQTLoiiYsa8p134t/YwwPrJtdIe0uocDnL0cjQfw6dA96g4iT9bfLKBnLupVGQ6rXAK8qxMNR9b71XKWtvsWlWEXpS1XyT7iJxGcch9rsmHTx@IFJlFS6ZcIyj6RKcKRcE5y2rLx3Pm88eSQERimEzSKEY/BnPQ4IYKn20pNv99IRQqPL7gLNUWalXiW@cVhPcyTCQJdseIKaJP45iBnqQKNha4yHBddjrVn26nta8hpE242667mi9ARTc/aB@gPl5B6MOHoIP@1rd3ZXO3a3wp3e2plEeE@jqlIfFlFFGQMJQz7peWnHCVaHQFiP0JpPYuOewSXPykX6ZmtrpVkutWKLQI319tLIU1W3bzc2Z4Z0yQ9Fv1@t9KFSxcEWoftA0hIBMyYvzNZdctt3SQ7fMk4DOuPbNRjKya@g0CBLXll2yaQ/rRIB0cNSE1OOq0XHQODZ2XQcBxM25CLTcSy9jrkENSHnKi7ln9phOtqF/N8Pz1uy45e/2uUFhYst2tkQZwkVQPqTpBPTGgfkpDzTHv070V8aS5Ih5bnjJIQ/kwOnhcq4PvDJ6TUFJNjvkNTx7MNt9t49ppcU6IX40QrxYx1ARCc/pwDvbkSS2w/xlgIzajmjXxrF5zR7o0pBcQhIP9YnfgJH2Rke7tR7qHpF20A0MbtpRmGcxUn2b1Fh@3aqY22VynVDGipNSNOZk6tzmjVzaHThIZppqRGxqmjcxMJ8kOXH4wXGCbEZCiGNES63I2Y6rpblLBysXr2PA6TuPd8uBFb3DpxH9jaL65aQY4T/Spm2hibXxLa5Eiri4pkiwdXJ@WFgwuXSz/aHWjZL1ybPpwEXlpiLyVMdoRDt5plIZUS5dq7NG8NjnliFNLPE3medLICSt2S6CpCYCAk8/rvBCmh9BAlHyvoalA841AW2z2E2uNwm2if2W1StSMPDZ@kjTKOW7H6UK3hvQZEzMNEk13w78@u1omTqWdt/Mtl6Yy5GJgOKyJgigzCZ6LtZZRQQy0yfs375qzGgwvYSu6yI0cXTpZa2sYbPs1lgoWs3xScWrtr4b4D0wwhVmWCz9ME37DbDdkm80j4lEyIb1e1i6hXTI5HFScxc6h6Niv5Cg1ZM665Hyr/VKT@Z2iXtkNhV6xIfHy/buOQ5vrdmCjyuQfmf9FErRHw5BICFqlmPBZgt4CDoJCOcw3uis9bNk45In2pjzUTHkhjSYBJYshlC/fPCejvJbdiH8xiP8u@HXKp8s659JRbBu9Tltt@FUbCphyIqTGtUBtiL8cJtuSFJa6RPhnpvSYQSHPqD8nXLNScI6I5hFL9tT5/UXHhR83/jxyuHLG7AsohW@2j9s5MxuIcb6EUGK6pI23jUJbtVnZ9n6bOQYDmiUxxl/bBfBoler58q5tBos5oFHYBZzZkm342xgfXfaJZ06eVHXuG3cV5doIjpqlPcpdvy0MulMRsAU6aQ5hb2B6yhAhU2ys7olUq2XTRJkb4YgHHHObHlv4LNbkZyzxXyklVVPqPfc5K932EGtqXwpNuUjIqP@l7ISuMyoGqdt1/2aA/QXUr7MGH9roa6bxClv4yN7YwgXzuT32wzkv5Hq572kISTWP6mdZBZdAzM6p2Jvpix14vrCliYLUDpa4F9tnO7A9MWx/4XoOZj7HlE28dVnUGdr6x8cKaEKePYeUCr/86vqnW@kP3S/Th0FBz5D5CH@duwX6xtoO29k0xAzTVI2YjJrrzS@woeW7o6/RijIqAHLYgcd@lBPbqcH2Pde3HM4GD4INSX1b2yWLC6CqDpBfA9OnWkyqgGnxUKB@rQX1fcGzHgLTyrGgcrN@5YL2qXDoXF/yOyLMPg/ouO6K7fnqWIoDTWiqZQ/SjmIRg@0o1lBG2fMfK3tvDs6wGg5WFlkFKKT4jSlZdbB7K@Ok@hi7vrXdKLGmDnBJWXFBvGH@BusAdDq8fl9JPVkSc@9PEbeKaOgU/Hf3EfxYssRUXiBZAwVgs@xLi3/GryAvTeDo6JLwWyNh@z0eZdoklADVgy1JzLA5hBoyhQNTnZqWWuV1@Uo2XPCi6iXDvpLlwE9s2fu2p1hINbYXPqaRq5@Yu8Cti9rqS1wbPVdC3pI5/EkTNk1DjBvM@wq8a5JCcAUBDkWwEyxv6dLpVZ2sWl/54@nbg4QkMWOBE7p9qHJYVnSOqGf7qWxnor0aov/JFGwWES8AjzZZZDqFQDBB1HFru47wuwLhTTjByY3dN1Hcwfq/K9aozVpfGTjzs7RnDbyLJ3hHplaHTwyYufu6297et9v9j5ILL6KxB6u7@UOEYxvZvHCru3cf2ZYejRgC@SA/WL@8haJTon@CeikPMbgFu4W/mQshbAbA6qvh/G3V8bavHMxHxgMo9hLsGckFrb5xtiOQ61og@CSB@tqNxaoJVHNXI2NHWLPczQNJcs8ozMs4LuK0otheYJWyTABFwAUkVRp4g05VKC3MY4@Dpkfuo869X9ks3CX0z9kOS4ONqNmFXE5a4mUO2wNrRFzA0S3oVKvArG9UjbEbGtZBG1dAQww5XF3M94LExlJhuPEY2DYD2P21dJ3o122@DO8u6uRuzH/OdoFJOhuSN6lG3a0zExWwVym6vDu03JXpo/bqqRYWjfiqyJFCXS8Kc7R@tOnqCrItEsNnQEQYHTqf9qze6za98vqTTfbr/QVrNSjdCyyRobNwxVUaiqJVV62iN9PFDlOw3xkh680hgToPWIk9arWaPExrcXywLWAfGI@tK48jysUYPLplzW1earfb7X9/PiBnn66vD2R48Bn@f7G@rMJYwifgnnnbaYZu5xxCAPEujHk3iBd9fHSaeU0m02KV7NbLqne/xXpL@fx/)

### Explanation

```
'
  L         Push ord code of 'L' onto stack
   | q'ol'
    q       Print that as a character
      ' l   Push ord code 'l' onto stack
            IP goes over right bound, so mirror it
         '
       o    Push ord code 'o' onto stack
     q      Print 'o' as character
   |        Mirror the IP
    q       Print 'l' as character
            Since there's no terminating condition, this continues forever
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC V2 (Commodore C64) 33 BASIC Bytes, 31 characters with BASIC keyword abbreviations

```
0?"{SHIFT+L}{CTRL+H}{CTRL+N}";:FORI=0TO1STEP0:?"OL";:NEXT
```

Quick explanation:

- Printing the control characters H stops from switching between CBM Graphics mode and Business case mode (with the latter being upper and lower case characters)
- Printing the control character N will switch to business case mode
- Setting up a `FOR/NEXT` loop with a step of `0` is a continuous loop
- Then printing the OL will be in lower case mode

Please see the screen shot for this in action.

[image: Commodore C64 Lololol challenge]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 389 bytes

```
L is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 l 2 r 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.[L]o is waiting at Writer's Depot.l is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:s 1 r 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Post Office:w 3 l 2 r 1 l.Switch to plan L.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZBBC8IwDIX/yrt5K6i3nQUvAwceBIeHMroZrE1pI/Xf121MFBFhXhJ4JF/ei@g75VyCIpImIddBCw6BxIRFxMZ4FrVlCH@IRcISFiuEqVtVUXO5eWh4HaNxnQnoeCD2yxVHwa5tqTET7k0pXM8IT5aqyxP/NmT/8BvHG3O9zst0ZL6OpXBfUiasXx9T@0TSnIcZb7VDqXJ@AA)

First Taxi answer. Try learning Taxi, I promise that you won't regret it. This was one of the most fun challenges I've done so far.

**Explained**:
First of all, we go to Writer's Depot, where a string `L`  is waiting. Then, we go back to Post Office to ship them off to STDOUT. Then, we go back to Writer's Depot to pick up string `ol`. With string `ol`, we go to Zoom Zoom to buy some fuel. We go to Post Office to print them, and then loop. Here's the problem though: we don't have enough money. We are earning less than the fuel cost. Solution? Pick up `o` and `l` as two separate passengers! That way, the both pay the fare of 0.07/mile so we can afford the 1.45/gallon fuel.

Each gallon carries them 18 miles. Based on the map, I estimate that the trip is 10 miles back and forth, and we carry them 7 miles. 10/18 = 0.55555 gallons. 0.55555 gallons costs around 0.8 dollars at Zoom Zoom. 7*0.07 is only 0.49 dollars, while 7*(0.07+0.07) for two passengers is 0.98, which leave 0.18 to spare. Profit.

***Just for fun***:
<sub>Say we're traveling at an average of 30 mph. Then, the trip is 20 minutes long back and forth. We can make three trips in an hour.  0.18*3 = 0.54. Townsburg Taxi Company, Inc had better be paying us! To maximize profit, we can carry three passengers at once: maybe `o` `l` and `ol`. This yields 2.01/hour. To maximize the maximized profit, we can carry them on longer routes. If we run all 360 miles on a full tank before dropping them off at the Post office, we can get fired and around 3.8 an hour if we plan carefully.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 11 bytes

```
A{\o\lA}\LA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVRNb6MwEL37V4w4Jd0mCpG2UqNmpRz2tv8gcKDgltGCjYyTtIry29NxIHwFw26369vg8cx7jzeTvetYiuU5U/IV1qAcxzlvjp70ks3J@7U5U8wYpplUGvL3nNFJeUqZW8fx4Q6WD4wdYkw4JFxMTJUp/IDFigEdfAGposvX7cKnizU8fIdARO3PT2t4LF@Ys6fqC1aFSOGyiiKK3CoSFBmAVe5LC4ZbFy1vLz1dH9b07ui0r80pqEQ1he6hGghPdZf@rCs2Ad@Klugza@IVFhawPM@xF70KglTYHc76Y6A2wEO5PMn5eMVModDg/FRKqnvYiTTQYYziFZ5VEP7mOgcUoGN@aamCdO6MliQPzvkb6smU2bF1FD2OCdqwKcIM3H6rXq86drUd49Ro9Dd9RshKvQPS8O40BJBnCWVwRYJGGAZaqv@k5WlEy4L1zMJ6mO0X2mWEmn2EaLltW8tpRj7wzWRsVzP3dij2rX3Ulsy1S/YFVHsoUuO9adlxZ7nbLdTKgXdXNbnb31SWKJxQZtZEFz2ba3gVG/C5jsi884NCzSelYNNBDE3NAgH0OiP3o8i12oUapWhMRBgHJKUZCS3LzI6IPQI2aS5tNJvr5N8Gs4PgptPJ2umvHHPTpqlsk7LxwPkD)

Interpreter breaking version. Would run forever otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 8 bytes

```
L#∞(ol
```

Implicitly prints `L`, then infinitely loops over implicitly printing `ol`. The parenthesis makes `o` and `l` into one statement, since a loop can only execute one statement. (In barrel, parentheses are self-closing.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 31 bytes

```lua
u=io.write u"L"::x::u"ol"goto x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/1DYzX6@8KLMkVaFUyUfJyqrCyqpUKT9HKT2/JF@h4v9/AA)

Comment: [Has to capitalize first L so here is the version.](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/1DYzX6@8KLMkVaFUyUfJyqrCyqpUKT9HKT2/JF@h4v9/AA "Lua – Try It Online")

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear Nice, thanks

Answer (score 1):

### [GForth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/) 30 bytes

```
: A ." L" 0 1 do ." ol" loop ;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch (30 Bytes)

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO L
:a
ECHO ol
GOTO :a
```

If you're willing to ignore `@ECHO OFF`, then it's 25 bytes instead.

Comment: You could get rid of `@echo off` without printing echo stuff by prefixing each line (except `:a`) with `@`s. Plus, as an alternative solution, you can output without newline by doing `set/p=Text to output<nul`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 25 bytes

```
main=putStr$'L':cycle"ol"
```

To return an infinite string, only 13 bytes required:

```
'L':cycle"ol"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 9 bytes

```
00000000: 3E 4C FF 3B 3B F6 20 EE
00000008: 03
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMXRVMnBXc3BSMnUDIzUzByEDB1VXBwPj/fwA)

### Explanation

```
  ld a, $4C ; Load the ASCII code of "L" into a
  rst $38   ; Jump past the end of the program (print "L") and push the next address (loop) to the stack

loop:
  dec sp    ; \
  dec sp    ; _} Push the last value (the address of loop) back to the stack by moving the stack pointer by 2 downwards
  or $20    ; Switch from uppercase to lowercase (idempotent). $4C ("L") -> $6C ("l"), $6C ("l") -> $6C ("l")
  xor $03   ; Toggle A between $6C ("l") and $6F ("o")

; ... the program runs (executes NOPs) until PC = $8000 where it prints A, then returns to the address on the stack (which is always loop)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BrainCrash](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainCrash), <s>43</s> 22 bytes.

```
^^+++++++++++.>>[.<.>]
```

I'll golf off later.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVNNb5tAEL37VwzKNgGxgHGcNDWG@FCp7aWXVuohihHGa7MyXgi71Ekd8tfdWT5kJUhodt68nTf7FkpW5TenC8OrZeXlRZrk3ooLr0QYnD@jC6hlsmUwgxZZVQkXaZXIzC1zkEVdpcxdpTAHLspauepZ4RaVJWInYVNU8PLveVRLBlJVPFWBXh6SSnCxlcH@BRb70Pw8of7Yx/eue32fTqf0GlH/S5v5/rSvjun1tYX7CA/HOpRtgAUXOpNVGhzbIwDxAp2G8/nV97iIv8XsKjgtl/b5caPowZ270eOpJ4z4xmz3vHnUs45aRMhw/uv31x8/I91eoVhZywzVqKxXeCLNoETZNvUPGc8Z5ExsVabhiKimGSEN0q3uVeTrUGZ8o7DTAh0ITX9yR2@7c97SOzqluGjPJtgBldA8UxOtowbskMRQi5xJSeJL3a3RcKMFtkylkyO54CJy/PtWBEecpVkFk5ubhv1FPzRPj7HrfEuLNQufDoaByad0v9ZriIDsH0j5GI47IRNT20bACvB@Sek42qEyGmNuD1yzjyFKWffjWZfafgDOB4p130XHnyE3ABfKigtl4pwDAxs/QOvkgBzhERp4HVp14XUYLIDL95XLc2X5vrI8V96GSrodZAIjIGjD8cmgRqPN6BlFtTZbe01Lc/rR4rC/fvxaKNnp68db0p66YduGxI1LPL6BNdtwwdYDGOSJVMA3ZBf1Xwp2aPqdqPrBENtGS97ZYTROZFqB/oPIAvssTv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
:p⌋
Lo”↑∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/36rgUU83l0/@o4a5j9omPuqY9/8/AA)

The first line is a helper function which prints a copy of its input and returns its input converted to lowercase.

`Lo”` pushes the string `"Lo"` to the stack, and `↑∞` calls the above function infinitely. Leading quotation marks can be omitted at the start of a line.

The same could be done in a single line with [`Lo”⟨:p⌋⟩∞`](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9nYWlh//9Mb@KAneKfqDpw4oyL4p@p4oie//8).

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;++i;){process.stdout.write(i<2?"L":"ol")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PWwFpbO9Nas7qgKD85tbhYr7gkJb@0RK@8KLMkVSPTxsheyUfJSik/R0mz9v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
{∇⍞←'ol'}⍞←'L'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRR/uj3nmP2iao5@eo10KZPur//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
p\LWp"ol
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vyDGJ7xAKT/n//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Etch](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/Etch), 23 bytes

```
do
:outnnl"lo";
forever
```

Comment: This looks like it outputs "lololololol", you need a capital L.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
'Lv
'l>,'o,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X9ynjUs@x01HP1/n/HwA)

**-3 bytes thanks to @emanresuA**
**-1 byte thanks to @WheatWizard**
[Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93) compatible version (1 byte more):

```
L"v
, <,"ol"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30epjEtHwUZHKT9H6f9/AA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Befunge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16090/tips-for-golfing-in-befunge) page for ways you can golf your program! I think this can be [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X99Ep49LJUbfRyVf//x8A) with some rearranging.

Comment: @emanresuA thanks! However I can't get over the fact that your code produces `Llolo...` instead of `Lolol...`

Comment: Oops. I was close...

Comment: @WheatWizard thank you too!

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 41 bytes

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I'd though I'd make a Rust contribution. Here's the code:

```rust
fn main(){print!("L");loop{print!("ol")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDyUdJ0zonP78ALpCfo6RZW/v/PwA) Note that it will panic on TIO after the output exceeds 128 KiB. But it doesn't panic in my terminal!

Answer (score 1):

### PHP (25 chars)

```php
echo'L';for(;;print'ol');
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 24 bytes

This is my first answer in Clojure; I only started learning it recently.

```clj
(pr 'L)(while 1(pr 'ol))
```

To be honest I'm not quite sure myself why `(pr 'ol)` works, but it does.

Comment: `while 1` can be `loop[]`

Comment: @naffetS That doesn't work for me. `(loop[](pr 'ol))` only prints `ol` once before returning.

Comment: Nevermind sorry, you would need `(recur)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```rs
fn main(){print!("L");loop{print!("ol")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDyUdJ0zonP78ALpCfo6RZW/v/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
"olL"wo~.K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18pP8dHqTy/Ts/7/38A)

### Explanation

```
"olL"wo~.K
"olL"       Puts `olL` in the stack, `L` on the top
     w   K  Never ending loop
      o     Print the first element of the stack
       ~    Swap the stack
        .   Duplicate the first element of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
'L[ZL"ol
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYr1H2io3yU8nMgXKgoTBYA)

##### Explanation

```
'L        # Push the character "L"
  [       # Forever:
   ZL     #  Print top of stack with no trailing newline
     "ol  #  Push "ol" for the next iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

## Binary-encoded [Golifcal](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Golfical), 13 bytes

Hexdump of binary encoding:

```
00 70 01 00 4c 18 1b 00 6c 18 00 6f 1d
```

This binary version can be convered back to a runnable program image using the Encoder included in the github repository for the language, or run directly by adding the `-x` flag.

Original program image:

[image]

Magnified 70x with RGB colors labeled:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/) `--cpp`, 57 bytes

```fortran
#define p(s)call fput(s)
p('L')
1 p('o');p('l');goto1;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JckxCsAgDEDR3VMIHaJDB2ev0EuIGikEE9Rev6nQ6T/4yGON1M@GP1SPUvHu1YqbPicii/KsbSMOLvAm7AMMPu7QTuPFIdZeVN@MlNrUM4t8).

I [`#define`](https://techpubs.jurassic.nl/manuals/0630/developer/MPro7F90CD_RM/sgi_html/ch07.html) a macro `p()` to save typing `call fput('x')` for every letter. And good old `goto` is mostly harmless.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
"L"^~"ol"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWK5V8lOLqlPJzlCB8qDBMGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 45 Bytes

```python
print('Lo',end='')
while 1:print('lo',end='')
```

[Try
it
online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ90nX10nNS/FVl1dk6s8IzMnVcHQCiqVg5D6/x8A)

Seems ungolfable.

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 42 bytes

SAS gives "the ultimate" answer in 42 bytes ;-)

The code:

```
data;put'L'@;do while(1);put'ol'@;end;run;
```

Human readable:

```
data;
  put 'L' @;
  do while(1);
    put 'ol' @;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

```
'L'o'lo'oo30.
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJ0wnbydsbydvbzMwLiIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Byte-based instruction jumping](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Byte-based_Instruction_Jumping), 8 bytes

```
↑L↑o↑l,L
```

How it works: When executed, the instructions stored in `↑` moves the instruction pointer to the right, prints the value stored there (`L`) and moves to the right again, making it point to the second `↑`. the second `↑` does the same again, except `o` is printed instead of `L`, and the third `↑` prints `l` and makes the instruction pointer point to `,`.

`,` also makes the instruction pointer move to the right (to the second `L`), but then it jumps back to the last byte with the same value as the current one (the first `L`), and moves right once more (to the second `↑`). Now it ends up in an infinite loop where it moves forward, prints `o`, moves forward, prints `l`, moves forward, jumps to the first `L`, moves forward, prints `o` et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

## [Basic](http://www.yabasic.de), 20 bytes

```
?"L";:DO:?"ol";:LOOP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/317JR8naysXfyl4pPwfI8vH3D/j/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
for(x='L';process.stdout.write(x);)x='ol'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9Io8JW3UfduqAoPzm1uFivuCQlv7REr7wosyRVo0LTWhMonZ@j/v8/AA)

-2 from Dom Hastings

Comment: I think the initial value of `x` could just be `'L'` for -2!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 7 bytes

```
'L{§ᶴol
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCInTHvCp+G2tG9sIiwiIiwiIiwiMy4xLjAiXQ==)

Lolololololol

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.3.1, 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/i-want-8-bits-for-every-character/265917#265917)

```
⍢(&pf"ol")1&pf@L
```

[See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__4o2iKCZwZiJvbCIpMSZwZkBMCg==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Hussy.Net](https://github.com/tacosontitan/Hussy.Net), 17 bytes

```cs
A("L");R(A,"ol");
```

- `A` is an append function that simply writes the specified input to the output stream.
- `R` is a repeater function that repeats the specified action with the specified input until an optionally specified escape condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

## Arduino, 82 bytes

```
void setup(){Serial.begin(300);Serial.print("L");}void loop(){Serial.print("ol");}
```

Arduino nicely splits our program into a "run once" section and a "run forever" section already.

Comment: What does `Serial.begin(300)` do?

Comment: Opens serial communications at 300 baud. 9600 is more common in practice, but it's one digit longer to write :P

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 28 bytes

```
t->t+1
t=0
(0,0)
([0...t],0)
```

The first line is a ticker, which automatically increases the number.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l0ntlrcvqw)

Decreasing the byte count can be done by using a custom interactive slider (but I didn't include it because it feels like cheating): [Try here!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1rslczemxu)

Comment: You forgot to include the labels in your code.

Answer (score 0):

## /// 9 bytes

```
L/./ol./.
```

Of course, you'll have to wait for the *end of time* to see the output, but wasn't this part of the challenge? (-;

Answer (score 0):

## [><x>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dead_fish), 58 bytes

Makes use of the fact that the accumulator is bound to the range `[0, 255]`.

```
iiissdddddoddsiiiiiiii>iiiov
                      ^oddd<
```

### Explanation

**Initializer**

```
iii                      Increase the accumulator to 3
   s                     Square it to get 9
    s                    Square it again to get 81
     ddddd               Reduce the accumulator by 5 to get 76
          o              Print the ASCII value of the accumulator, "L"
           dd            Decrement the accumulator by 2
             s           Square it to get 74^2 & 255, which is 100
              iiiiiiii   Increase the accumulator by 8
```

**The loop**

```
>        Force the IP to the right
 iii     Increment by 3
    o    Print the ASCII value of the accumulator, "o"
     v   Force the IP downward
     <   Force the IP to the left
  ddd    Decrement by 3
 o       Print the ASCII value of the accumulator, "l"
^        Force the IP upward
```

Comment: Going from 76 to 108 can be done in 8 bytes `siiisiii`. You can save spaces by folding the first line in half, which gives [36 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728OCexOCO1eMGCpaUlaboWN1UyMzOLi1NAIL9YoYyrLB8oYAMSBNFcdiDxOIhaqBaYVgA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 25 bytes

```perl
print"L";print'ol'while 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRMlHyRrMUM/PUS/PyMxJVTD8//9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 11 bytes

```
#"L"#"ol"?2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 41 bytes

```
fn main(){print!("L");loop{print!("ol")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDyUdJ0zonP78ALpCfo6RZW/v/PwA)

Comment: Exact same code already posted twice more than an year and half ago by [Sylvester Kruin - try Codidact](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111322/sylvester-kruin-try-codidact) and [code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108556/code).