# Average Two Letters

Tags: code-golf, string, math, arithmetic, statistics

## Introduction

Every letter in the English alphabet can be represented as an ASCII code. For example, `a` is `97`, and `S` is `83`. As we all know, the formula for averaging two numbers \$x\$ and \$y\$ is  \$\frac{x+y}{2}\$.  I'm pretty sure you can see where this is going.  Your challenge is to average two letters.

## Challenge

Your program must take two letters as input, and output the average of the ASCII values in it. If the average is a decimal, you should truncate it.

- Input will always be two ASCII letters. You can assume they will always be valid, but the case may vary. Basically, both letters will be in the range `97-122` or `65-90`. The second letter will always have a greater ASCII value than the first. If your language has no method of input, you may take input from command line arguments or from a variable.
- You must output the ASCII character signified by the average of the two numbers. As stated above, it should always be truncated to `0` decimal places. If your language has no method of output, you may store it in a variable. Exit codes and return values are considered valid output methods.

## Example I/O

- `Input:  A, C`
  `Output: B`
- `Input:  a, z`
  `Output: m`
- `Input:  d, j`
  `Output: g`
- `Input:  B, e`
  `Output: S`
- `Input:  Z, a`
  `Output: ]`

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Please specify whether, for example, `B e` is a valid input.

Comment: Why is the output of the last example `U`? The value of `B` is 66 and the value of `e` is 101, which averages to 83.5, truncated to 83, which corresponds to `S`

Comment: If that example is correct, it will invalidate all of the existing answers.

Comment: Sorry. I read an ASCII table wrong and got 69 for `B`, not 66.

Comment: Could I enter for a non-ASCII compliant system?

Answer (score 9):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 20 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>(char)(a+b>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5yRWKSDYIEIO7s02/@JtnZJtnYaIL6mRqJ2kp2doeZ/a67wosySVI00DfVEdU0N9WR1TU3r/wA)

Answer (score 8):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>13</del> <del>12</del> 10 bytes

Binary (xxd):

```
00000000: a182 0002 c4d0 e8cd 29c3            ..........
```

Listing:

```
A1 0082     MOV  AX, [0082H]    ; load two chars into AH and AL from command line
02 C4       ADD  AL, AH         ; AL = AL + AH 
D0 E8       SHR  AL, 1          ; AL = AL / 2 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write to console 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
```

Standalone PC DOS executable.  Input is via command line, output to console.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Only 5 bytes if written as a function :-)

Comment: @CodyGray only 4 bytes as a snippet or a MACRO.  Not sure where the "line" is though... :)

Comment: Functions are always permitted, as are full programs, per house code golfing rules. Not sure about macros, though; interesting suggestion. Although avoiding that 1-byte RET is probably not going to be enough to make a difference most of the time...

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
OSHỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/2OPh7p7///8rpSjpKChlKQEA)

## Explanation

```
OSHỌ  Main Link: takes (a, b)
O     (ord(a), ord(b))
 S    sum; ord(a) + ord(b)
  H   halve; (ord(a) + ord(b)) / 2
   Ọ  chr
```

Comment: [Rajneesh A.K.A. OSHỌ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajneesh)

Answer (score 7):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 163 bytes

```
software inside a computer
a robot+a man+a keypad+a plan=a PC
still,P.C.this,P.C.that?i await a day i crush a PC
resist P.C,Google,or an Apple
i do Linux,i suppose
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?LYwxDsIwEAT7vGJ7rPwAIZSChiJfuOCDnHB8lu@ikNcHC9GMpphd06dvVBmSTSKD8NClrM61I1Sd1E@EhXLjm/dCsUlJlM@EcejMJaUw9kPvs9hfyC8C2ki8vUXaIXjU1Wb8JpVNzNHScFN9JQ5aQRnXUhJ3gqi4S14/QWBrKWp8jMMxUfwC)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

(I actually use PC myself. )

Comment: Love the idea of this language.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
(+/<.@%#)&.(3&u:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NbT1bfQcVJU11fQ0jNVKrTT/a3KlJmfkK6g7qSvYKqQpqDs6q0NFcqEiiVUwkXSoSEqWusJ/AA)

- `(+/<.@%#)`  truncated average...
- `&.` ["Under"](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampdot), which applies a transform, then the verb it modifies -- truncated avg in this case -- then the inverse transform....
- `3&u:` convert to ascii byte integer.

That is, it converts each letter to its ascii number, gets the truncated average of those, and applies the inverse of "convert to ascii number", which takes an ascii number and returns a letter.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>56</s> 37 bytes

```r
intToUtf8(mean(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzOvJCQ/tCTNQiM3NTFPoxTICsn3zCvRKE4GcnWUlDSB4L9SYorSfwA)

**Description**

- `intToUtf8()` converts the average into its ASCII character.
- `mean()` takes the average which is automatically truncated.
- `utf8ToInt()` converts the inputs into two ASCII numbers.
- `scan()` allows inputs.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! A few tips: 1. You can use an anonymous function, so don't need the `f=`; 2. You don't need `print`; 3. In this case, it is actually shorter to take input with `scan` that to define a function; 4. `floor` is not needed: if you feed a non-integer numeric to `intToUtf8`, R truncates it automatically before converting to character. Also, TIO must have been experiencing issues when you tried it; the `base` package is included. All in all, your solution can be shortened to [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzOvJCQ/tCTNQiM3NTFPoxTICsn3zCvRKE4GcnWUlDSB4L9SYorSfwA "R – Try It Online").

Comment: @RobinRyder Thanks for the reduction!

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{""<<(a+b).sum/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6laScnGRiNRO0lTr7g0V9@o9n9BaUmxQrS6o7O6jnpiFZBIyVKP1ctNLKiuSa5Ji9ZK1kvOSCwqjq39DwA)

Comment: Huh. TIL the functionality of `str << int`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-ir` `-oc`, <del>5</del> 2 bytes (SBCS)

Works in all 3 test cases.

```
+½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fXttI/1HLkv//HZ0B)

## Explanation

````
-ir will *not* try to evaluate the input
+   Add them
 ½  Halve the value
-oc Output all as a character, if possible

Implicit print. The output is print nice by default.
```
````

Comment: Loading issue. I just tried the first test case and it didn't error.(I got to clone the most recent Keg interpreter.)

Comment: Using `-ir` and `-oc` will allow this two byter: `+½`

Comment: What a great solution. I think we cannot go shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 8 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$.5*+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZRc9US1tfKbFK6f9/AA)

**Explanation:**

Sum, multiply by 0.5 and convert to ASCII.

```
`c$.5*+/ / the solution
      +/ / sum (add-over)
   .5*   / multiply by 0.5
`c$      / convert to ASCII
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 56 bytes

```bash
printf \\x$(printf %x $[`printf "(%d+%d)/2" \'$1 \'$2`])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTSEmpkJFA8pWrVBQiU6AcpQ0VFO0VVM09Y2UFGLUVQxBhFFCrOb///8d/zsDAA)

Comment: 1) The outer pair of quotes is needed only because the `\x`, so better escape just that single character; 2) The deprecated `$[`..`]` is shorter for arithmetic evaluation; 3) The old `\``..`\`` is shorter for subcommand, except when needs escaping; 4) The inner pairs of quotes are needed only because of `'`, so better escape just those characters. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTSEmpkJFA8pWrVBQiU6AcpQ0VFO0VVM09Y2UFGLUVQxBhFFCrOb///8d/zsDAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork: Do you want to post this as an answer? Or should I edit my post?

Comment: Feel free to edit your post. Is mostly your work. I didn't had the patience this time to juggle with the `printf`s.

Comment: You have an error in the version posted here: the closing `"` should be on the left side of the nearby space to avoid touching the next argument's first character, the ``\``. (The TIO code is correct though.)

Comment: @manatwork: Thanks for pointing me to this.

Answer (score 5):

## Shakespeare Programming Language, 144 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxDsIwEAS/sg@Ijj5dCopUIKVCiOLsHGBC7BCfBXm9sanoZlazcXnmvKPuwZ@GjslODXVW0bc0WPFS4bz3KitqAvYjanWp1h4W8ZidH3/PPz2FBBehd8ErBXXiFUb0LQXKFtOMcN1K1INh3A2WlYZFeCqfjXJm8wUj)

(Whitespace added for readability)

```
/.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]
Ajax:Open mind.
Puck:Open mind.
You is the quotient betweenthe sum ofyou I a big cat.
Speak thy.
```

Simple enough, just finds the average. ASCII characters and numbers are identical in SPL, so this language was ideal for the task.

Answer (score 4):

## dzaima/APL, 11 bytes

```apl
(+/÷≢)⍢⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P@1R2wQNbf3D2x91LtJ81LvoUd/UUOfg/0AKKJGm7qiuoO6szgXjJgK5VQhuCpCbpf4fAA) dzaima/APLs `⎕UCS` - convert to/from char currently ignores the fractional part of the given number, so no floor is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 7 bytes

```
~~+2/,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@vq9M20tdx@P/f0RkA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda*A:chr(sum(map(ord,A))/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcu9CoMwEADg2T5FtruTg4KjoBB8jOpwNgQtzQ/RDvryacTtW7547EvwTbbdmL/iZiO1bt9Lwu3n0EnEkAxromdD2YakhGe1evVC0MAwALFCkMLzpin8AE3to4pp9fsVGLoe2GIh5T8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <del>42</del> 41 bytes

```lua
a=...print(a.char(a:byte()+a:byte(2)>>1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0VZPT6@gKDOvRCNRLzkjsUgj0SqpsiRVQ1MbyjDStLMz1NT8D1RbBQA)

Removed 1 byte using [ouflak's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195630/71126) of taking input as a single command line argument.

Takes input as a single command line argument of two characters. Uses the convenient operator precedence of `>>`.

Note that this is actually a full standalone Lua 5.3 program, because command line arguments are accessible as a top-level vararg.

Comment: You beat me: `print(string.char((io.read():byte()+io.read():byte())/2))`.

Comment: Thanks to your tip on my answer, I think I just figured out how to [save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0VZPT6@gKDOvRCNRLzkjsUgj0SqpsiRVQ1MbyjDStLMz1NT8D1RbBQA) on yours.

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 23 characters

```
[explode|add/2]|implode
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq -Rr '[explode|add/2]|implode' <<< 'AC'
B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z86taIgJz8ltSYxJUXfKLYmMxfM/f/f0ZkrsYorJetffkFJZn5e8X/doP@6RQA)

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 28 bytes

```
=CHAR((CODE(A1)+CODE(B1))/2)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
a\b=Char(sum(Int[a,b])÷2)
```

TIO was timing out for me, so only tested at REPL.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzEmydY5I7FIo7g0V8MzryQ6UScpVvPwdiPN/w7FGfnlCuqO6jHqzupcUJ4hkBel/h8A)

Comment: "You must output the ASCII character signified by the average of the two numbers". Shouldn't your output be a single ASCII character?

Comment: Thanks for catching that, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Preproc](https://gitlab.com/PavelBraginskiy/preproc), 1187 bytes

```
#define A
#define B,
#define C,,
#define D,C
#define E,D
#define F,E
#define G,F
#define H,G
#define I,H
#define J,I
#define K,J
#define L,K
#define M,L
#define N,M
#define O,N
#define P,O
#define Q,P
#define R,Q
#define S,R
#define T,S
#define U,T
#define V,U
#define W,V
#define X,W
#define Y,X
#define Z,Y
#define a Z H
#define b,a
#define c,b
#define d,c
#define e,d
#define f,e
#define g,f
#define h,g
#define i,h
#define j,i
#define k,j
#define l,k
#define m,l
#define n,m
#define o,n
#define p,o
#define q,p
#define r,q
#define s,r
#define t,s
#define u,t
#define v,u
#define w,v
#define x,w
#define y,x
#define z,y
#define _(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,_,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,cg,ch,ci,cj,ck,cl,cm,cn,co,cp,cq,cr,cs,ct,cu,cv,cw,cx,cy,cz,da,db,dc,dd,de,df,dg,dh,di,dj,dk,dl,dm,dn,do,dp,dq,dr,ds,dt,du,dv,dw,dx,dy,dz,ea,eb,ec,ed,ee,ef,eg,eh,ei,ej,$,...)#$
#define $($a,$b)_($a $b z,y,y,x,x,w,w,v,v,u,u,t,t,s,s,r,r,q,q,p,p,o,o,n,n,m,m,l,l,k,k,j,j,i,i,h,h,g,g,f,f,e,e,d,d,c,c,b,b,a,a,`,`,_,_,^,^,],],\\,\\,[,[,Z,Z,Y,Y,X,X,W,W,V,V,U,U,T,T,S,S,R,R,Q,Q,P,P,O,O,N,N,M,M,L,L,K,K,J,J,I,I,H,H,G,G,F,F,E,E,D,D,C,C,B,B,A,A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RdLZbuJAEEbh@zyFxXARpKO8wVwAIXsgK4snmYzd3ez7Di@f@SFORSdSfW5KwrGZzsN0PnGfn798aPfGISqefKuEscyPzymbK5ybL6iYL7kwX3FpvubKfMO1@ZYb8x235nvuzFXuzTWq5gdq5kcezE88mp95Mr/wbH7lxVzn1dygbm7SMLdommNa5iSKo5//LCUxO1Kzx5kD3twmmDu0zV065h5dc5@eeUDfPGRgHjE0jxmZJ4zNUybmGVPznJl5wdy8ZGFesTSvWZk3rM1bNuYdW/OenfnjNCHF4Qm06dClR58BQ0aMmTBlxpwFS1as2bBlx54iJcqcU@GCS6645oZb7rinSo0HHnnimRdeqdOgSYuYD5y@yOH0GgKujevgurgero8b4Ia4EW6Mm@CmuBlujlvglrgVbo3b4La4HW6PT/ApXvft8XqXbXwH38X38H38AD/Ej/Bj/AQ/xc/wc/wCv8Sv8Gv8Br/F7/B7QkJICY6gxxAI@kF0CF1Cj9Anz9nZWeFX3p5Z/jSfkE8LH5pRPj08T7VVG7VWK7VUCzVXMzVVEzVWIzVUA9VXPdVVHdVWuge9ET0olapE/VMf6q96V29vh78/KlYt1VQNVVev6kU9qyf1qB5UTVXVvbpTt@pGXasrdakuVEWdq7IqqSLFwmf@tEhULES/o6NKXyplZ7li7uR4XrbzbKP8vVE6bMRE8fEqPlwlRMnXlpR@Kc3Ockm24ew823DfG@lhY0@0P17tszvYf23F31vvuRN9UD9e5k8b2Wxms5XN@Gem2XTZ9NkM2Wxns5PNbuHzPw)

Defines a macro `$` which can be called (as shown in the footer of the TIO link above)

This challenge is barely possible in preproc (pure macro) -- if the input can be non-alphanumeric characters too, it would not be possible.

I don't see any simple way to shorten this code -- it might be possible to make the part to take the (n)th element shorter, but that would come at the cost of making the initial macro definitions significantly longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>33</del> 32 bytes

<sup><sup>-1B from Embodiment of Ignorance using bit ops.</sup></sup>

Exactly as specified. For a Python 3 answer change the `/` into `//`.

```python
lambda a,b:chr(ord(a)+ord(b)>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfqGCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIVEnySo5o0gjvyhFI1FTG0QladrZGWr@LyjKzCvRSNRQclTSUXJW0tTkgoskAkWqUERSgCJZQJH/AA)

Comment: This could be just `/2` in Python 2.

Comment: I mean, [this way](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfqGCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIVEnySo5o0hDI78oRSNRUxtEJWlq6htp/i8oyswr0UjUUHJU0lFyVtLU5IKLJAJFqlBEUoAiWUCR/wA).

Comment: I see, I thought the complete function body can be turned into ```/2```.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `lambda*s:chr(sum(map(ord,s))/2)`

Comment: Nice golfing, but now it is an almost exact duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195621/85052) answer. (The names of the parameters are changed.)

Comment: `lambda a,b:chr(ord(a)+ord(b)>>1)` saves a byte

Comment: `For a Python 3 answer change the / into //. ` part is outdated

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```lua
s=io.read()print(s.char(math.floor((s:byte()+s:byte(2))/2)))
```

Takes the two letters with no delimeters, i.e. `AB`, `j$`, `|1`, etc....

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2DYzX68oNTFFQ7OgKDOvRKNYLzkjsUgjN7EkQy8tJz@/SAMolFRZkqpRrKkNY@kYaWrqA7Hm//@OzgA)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to PhillipRoman*

Comment: There are shorter Lua solutions. They look also interesting, @outflak.

Comment: @ouflak I'd like to clarify that my solution is a full standalone Lua 5.3 program, because command line arguments are always accessible as a top-level vararg

Comment: @PhilipRoman, So what TIO is doing is virtually running a command line Lua 'shell' and passing in the arguments appropriately? Interesting....

Comment: @PhilipRoman, I assumed naturally that that's what you were doing. I was pondering how TIO did it. Somehow they have to emulate "lua myscript.lua a z".

Comment: @ouflak Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. Yeah, the fact that TIO shows the time taken just like the linux "time" command, seems to indicate that there is indeed a real shell involved.

Answer (score 3):

## Zsh, <s>33</s> 31 characters

```
a=({$1..$2} 0)
echo ${a[$#a/2]}
```

This one does no character code conversion.

Sample run:

```
manatwork ~ % set -- A C    

manatwork ~ % a=({$1..$2} 0);echo ${a[$#a/2]}
B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/0VajWsVQT0/FqFbBQJMrNTkjX0GlOjFaRTlR3yi29v///47/nQE)

Comment: Very clever use of brace expansion! I managed [27 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216102/15940) in a more boring way :)

Answer (score 3):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

**Solution:**

```
10h$_avg
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)10h$_avg"AC"
"B"
q)k)10h$_avg"az"
"m"
q)k)10h$_avg"dj"
"g"
```

**Explanation:**

<s>Unfortunately the space is needed.</s> Turns out the space isn't necessary!

```
10h$_avg / the solution
     avg / calculate mean
    _    / floor
10h$     / cast to char
```

**Bonus:**

- `10h$-256+avg` for a 12 byte Q version (more/less hacky than `10h$(_)avg` for 10)

Answer (score 3):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 63 bytes

```
,
)
,
>[!(>[!
"=#="=#
  - ( >
) ( + -
!+< ) [
#=" !-<)
    #=".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fh0uTS4fLLlpRA4i5lGyVbYGYS0FBV0FDwY5LE0hqK@hyKWrbKGgqRHMBZRUUdW00gQoUFIAcvf//nVIB)

Super golfable, I'm sure - not really able to think in MarioLANG yet. Calculates \$\lfloor\frac{x+y}{2}\rfloor\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 15 bytes

```forth
: f + 2/ emit ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKWgrGOkrpOZmlihYA/kFCvllqUUQfkppgUJxQWJyKoSrp6SgoGunoATUk1ykYM2l7qig7qxQwKWeqKBeBaJTFNSzQLSTgnoqiI5SAEoVcP0HAA)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f      \ start a new word definition
  +      \ add top two stack arguments
  2/     \ divide top stack value by 2
  emit   \ output char of resulting ascii value
;        \ end word definition
```

Comment: The input requires `char`, *e.g.* `char a char c f` would output `b`.

Comment: More usable version: `: g char char + 2/ cr emit ;`, run like `g e B`, (outputs `S`), *etc.*  Note that it doesn't seem to matter which order the arguments are in, so `g B e` also outputs `S`.

Comment: @agc In gforth `'` will also work, so `'a 'b f` would also output `b` and looks much more similar to other languages

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
|*;:2@+/',{,|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/79Gy9rKyEFbX12nWqfm///EFAA)

[image]

Linear control flow: `,{,'+{*2':;@`

I decide to plug it in [the Hexagony brute forcer program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165095/69850), and it can't find a 12-byte program. At least for that specific linear code.

Other possible linear control flows:

```
,{,'+'2=':;@
,{,'+'2{=:;@
,},"+{*2':;@
,},"+'2=':;@
,},"+'2{=:;@
,{,'+{+2':;@
```

(none of them results in a 12-byte solution (there are only some non-halting 12-byte solutions); nevertheless, the brute force program has room for improvement.)

Comment: That's one horrific control flow D:

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```perl
$x+=ord for@ARGV;print chr$x>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lQts2vyhFIS2/yMExyD3MuqAoM69EITmjSKXCzs7w////if9TAQ)

Shortened to 30 bytes thanks to comment by [Dadsdy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/118038/dadsdy)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Can't you replace the >>1 with /2?

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 18 bytes

```
func[a][average a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OjE2OrEstSgxPVUhMfZ/QVFmXolCmkK0spKjkoKykrNSLBeSWCJIrApVLAUklqUU@x8A)

Takes the input as a list of two letters.

If this is not acceptable:

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 20 bytes

```
func[a b][a + b / 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OlEhKRZIaCskKegrGMX@LyjKzCtRSFNQVnJUAhLOSlwIkUSQSBWySApIJEvpPwA)

Comment: So Red's default behavior is to do the conversion to numbers and then back to letter for the output?

Comment: @Jonah The type of the result is implied by the first argument. `#"A" + 1` is `#"B"`; `1 + #"A"` is `66`

Comment: @Jonah From the documentation: "The full range of mathematical functions can be used with char! values. A Math Error is raised if the result of the arithmetic falls outside of the range 00 - 10FFFF (hexadecimal)."

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
Ymc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzI3@f9/dUcXdQA)

#### Explanation

```
Ym   % Implicit input: string of two letters. Implicitly convert to ASCII, and take mean
c    % Implicitly round down, and convert to char
     % Implicit display
```

Comment: It's fun to stay at the...

Answer (score 2):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 7 bytes

```
ii+2,k@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z8zU9tIJ9vh/39HhSgA)

Input is space sepatrated. Use invalid inputs at your own peril.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 32 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$s+=+$_}
[char]($s-shr1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzRCoJAEEXf5ysGGdtd1IdeA8HqMyJk0VEJI9s1itRv31at7tNhztzb3Z5sbMNt66hKB0fa1HYMB7JRGlE@walotDlLsoltzFa5CSCTEEuxP4pYHISaWb89X1cuL55rzwpHDHEA9KF5xcZI/Oq46LnEFClflWH7aHt/2FCF2fK4iIDk1yUF3/9NtftVApjAfQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 57 bytes

```
fun(x,y)=Strchr(floor((Vecsmall(x)[1]+Vecsmall(y)[1])/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P600T6NCp1LTNrikKDmjSCMtJz@/SEMjLDW5ODcxJ0ejQjPaMFYbzq0EcTX1jTQ1IVqVEpV0lJKVNAE)

**Description**

- `Vecsmall(x)[1]` gives the ASCII number of `x`.
- `Vecsmall(y)[1]` gives the ASCII number of `y`.
- `/2` gives the average.
- `floor()` truncates the average.
- `Strchr()` converts the average to its ASCII character.

Answer (score 2):

## Ceylon (named function) <s>74 68 65 64</s> 60

Contrary to e.g. Java, in Ceylon you can't directly add characters (The compiler complains with `Left operand must be of summable type: Character is not a subtype of Summable`). Instead, we first need to convert it to an integer, and afterwards back to character. This gives 74 bytes:

```ceylon
Character c(Character x,Character y)=>((x.integer+y.integer)/2).character;
```

We can write this shorter by using the `.hash` attribute instead of the `.integer` attribute, which for characters turns out to have the same implementation (returning the Unicode value of a character). This is 68 bytes:

```ceylon
Character d(Character x,Character y)=>((x.hash+y.hash)/2).character;
```

A more ceylonic way of doing this is to use the fact that Character is a Enumerable type, and implements the `.neighbour` and `.offset` methods. The average has an offset from the smaller which is half as large as the offset of the larger to the smaller. This even turns out slightly smaller, with 65 bytes.

```ceylon
Character a(Character x,Character y)=>x.neighbour(y.offset(x)/2);
```

Unfortunately most of this is the declaration of the types. We can reduce this slightly by having the method take a sequence (tuple/pair) of two characters instead of both individually – this removes one parameter, but adds `[...]` several times, coming to 64 bytes:

```ceylon
Character b(Character[2]c)=>c[0].neighbour(c[1].offset(c[0])/2);
```

An alternative way of making the type declaration shorter is an alias declaration. This only is worthwile from 3 usages of `Character`, which we have here, reaching 60 bytes:

```ceylon
alias C=>Character;C e(C x,C y)=>x.neighbour(y.offset(x)/2);
```

(The `.hash` version with alias comes to 63 bytes.)

[Try all the examples online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=2d8224b0fdce535de35e5695934f57dc)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 34 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b)=>chr(ord($a)+ord($b)>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9DsMgDIV3TmFFSICKkDqnELU9RpqB/CCaAVCSqVXPTp0obTzY77OfX/IpX6rkEyHU6ewCp1bSVmjT@YnHqUcWp222wpizyCU6l2FeZtBQE8Cq2ZVJdmeN3NEivg7sEccDV/NtxQajXJwG23nge6adYVMC3pt96HyEMT4Dxy/5uylgoA02BdRxpdR/XzxCUZJP/gI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 67 bytes

There should be a Wren answer for every Lua answer.

```
Fn.new{|a|String.fromCodePoint((a.bytes.reduce{|a,i|a+i}/2).floor)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xg@98tTy8vtby6JrEmuKQoMy9dL60oP9c5PyU1ID8zr0RDI1EvqbIktVivKDWlNDkVqE4nsyZRO7NW30hTLy0nP79Is/Z/cGVxSWquXkERSAfIXL3kxJwcDSVHZyVNTS5csolV@GRTsoCy/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <strike>59</strike> 53 Bytes

<strike>`i=>String.fromCharCode(Buffer.from(i).reduce((t,v)=>t+v)/2)`</strike>

`i=>String.fromCharCode((b=Buffer.from(i))[0]+b[1]>>1)`

```
> f('ae')
'c'
> f('ab')
'a'
> f('ac')
'b'
> f('ad')
'b'
> f('ae')
'c'
> f('aZ')
']'
> f('Be')
'S'
```

Bonus (Sorry if off topic, I'm not sure if this is allowed and couldn't find anything with a quick check. Please advise if this is actually a viable answer or not), here is the first answer written as NodeJS REPL input (making use of tabs to complete partial names):

`i=>St  .f  h   (Bu .f  (i).reduce((t,v)=>t+v)/2)` (43 bytes)

Note tabs might be malformed by page formatting.
Note pasting anything after the tab will suppress completion on some terminals.

Comment: Could this be shortened using `toString(36)` and `parseInt`?

Comment: Suggest `Buffer(i)` instead of `Buffer.from(i)` for **5 bytes**. I think this is the shortest possible solution in Javascript (which is definitely not the right tool for this job, sadly).

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 45 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_char_from_STDIN][T  T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   S _Read_char_from_STDIN][T  T   T   _Retrieve][T    S S S _Add][S S S T S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer_divide][T    N
S S _Print_as_character]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4FTg5OYEsBIdTAQyAgkAuUFBB4f//qEQA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation:**

Character inputs in Whitespace are always stored as unicode integers, so we don't have to do an explicit conversion manually. The program has the following pseudo-code:

```
int a = STDIN as character
int b = STDIN as character
int c = (a+b) integer-divided by 2
Print c as character to STDOUT
```

I also use the first input as a heap-address for the second input, since it's guaranteed to be non-negative. This saves a byte by using `SNS` (duplicate) twice instead of `SSSN` + `SNS` (push 0 and duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 46 bytes

```
,>,[-<+>]++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx04nWtdG2y5WW9smWtdON9pO284u1i5aGyIK5tmAQKydnZ3e//9OqQA)

```
,>,                             Takes input into cells 0 and 1
[-<+>]                          Sums the two values, storing the result in cell 0
++<                             Sets cell 1 to 2, and returns to cell 0
[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]  Divides cell 0 by cell 1
>>>.                            Moves to and outputs cell 3, where the quotient is stored
```

Comment: `,<,[>+<-]>[-[->+>]<[<<]>]>.` is only 27 bytes, and it does the division by 2 by basically decrementing the sum, decrementing the sum again only if the result is still greater than 0, and incrementing another tape value, all until the sum is 0.

Answer (score 2):

## (e)Lisp, 50 bytes

```
(insert (/ (+ (aref (read) 0) (aref (read) 0)) 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 10 bytes

```
rcirci+2/c
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rcirci%2B2%2Fc)

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 64 bytes

```
declare @ char='Z',@2 char='a'print char((ascii(@)+ascii(@2))/2)
```

assuming `@` and `@2` the input.

37 bytes if only put:

```
print char((ascii('B')+ascii('C'))/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 32 bytes

```sql
SELECT CHAR(AVG(ASCII(c)))FROM i
```

Input is taken via a pre-existing table \$i\$ with `CHAR(1)` column \$c\$, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

The two input characters are entered as separate rows. (Note that because SQL is set-based, this will calculate the average of an arbitrary number of inputs.)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

Saved 0 bytes, but got a giggle, thanks to @ceilingcat!

```c
(*c)()=L"\xd137048d쏸";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtLCsIwFAD3OcUjUJJIC34KCqGLgkuP0M3rS1qLGiWtUhTP4HU8lGcwtiI4m4GBoaQmCkFOSEmVbXjRm9liOU1X5vV4ch0a18EBGycVuzEYoC16QMhAoND/Uo6FfuXkh62SPL9Yj7WFYwURATozqmkhMoXjMWAMZQwkRyul2ff1tjt7B@lcs3sQ@Vq8qdpj3YbkantLbYe0@wA)

Comment: Can you write `\xd1` as a char?

Comment: @l4m2 Seg fault when I tried `(*c)()=L"Ñ37048d쏸";`

Comment: That's because tio use utf8

Comment: `(*c)()="??7???";` is 1 byte shorter than `c(a,b){b=a+b>>1;}`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP 7.3](https://php.net), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

-1 byte thanks to manatwork

```php
$x=function($a,$b){echo chr((ord($a)+ord($b))/2);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBDoMgDIbvPkVjTICMkOzsdNn2GM4DogQ9AEG8zPjsrho3e2j7/e3/e@PX290bnySZLlY9WRV7Z2kmedawOXRxChaUCZS60KLMLvtsGCvLK8uXfM3RGrsxjlBAlQBWRR6Ekxep@YES8XNiizicuD0/N6wxSrvQSWWAHplyhH1jMO/vnTIOBtdbii7@uwkgUJTYBGSaCiH@evq2aZ4s6xc)

Comment: I guess you intended to write “51 bytes” there. Assuming you count the TIO version which is 1 byte shorter than the one posted here.

Comment: And you got something wrong: either `(x+y)/2` or `x+y>>1`. I mean, if you use parenthesis, then division is shorter. The shift-right is used to avoid the need to use parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

## [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), <del>12</del> 8 bytes

```
APG+G>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fMcBd293OzvD//8RkAA)

Please advise on golfing skeeels.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: [There is auto-completion of brackets and semicolons. Also note that >>1 does the same thing as /2 and saves a bracket.](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fMcBd293OzvD//8RkAA)

Comment: It says Adam P. Goucher

Answer (score 2):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
,,+11##1+"\"/^"+1+<1+#;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVbb5tIFH7nV5zgB6BgYJys2nXjh6ZSo1aRFWXbh11CEYZxjRYYOjPkora/3T0DxmA79i5CaC7fuX/nUD3LFSsn6/UIVlJWYup5VcyT/FnGTzR3ZV0scu4mrPAqJqT35rX/5o/X5OKc/OllpaS84hS/4yXjYzLOynHV6NO00ZlXC@4tstKj5QNsjkdAbBjI4Rpuu6vbxi58VobBg0@U00JtSwcmPrlAxE2W0DKhkAl4/x6u/h7/9Q4uXB/BH97dAHHPcXU9/wLXtzcP51pWVIxLEM9CW3JWQMLynCYyY6WAzV1Kv9dU04QDIoVZuzUtB3780rSULoGVtMprYQrEzmCOW2uqAT7ZEkqGurls95uznJYm2nNj/u3BgrMZTPpr9VQcgwf9i4i/0SnoYEOHDvwQdzoEyyynIBksKNAnmtSSpqG@o0SJ0KdMmsTqbZcVOsiqgf2AhA4Y3OhBPH5EEEJdTuPU3JF2k5wJujmjuUD3WjiG2Jw1n1XhwJ0DCyEduHJgjvdBqNLl9Lnz8W3AyAlIVIVR0U6WEpjNwDCN3dxcgT0DsnOEdty4wqBSc24darAONIz3NdwFSkfFKtMKVQV3LlHRFVyCv6tlUKePxSLOY2RcCgseJ/9SKc70A/C2HpMXfBwZEJcp2sGNP8UEvhDQvI@8celsNvTpf/my70PzmTuQFIq4WJIPMda0OX1cKYbNMXDFVqyN1dtiikV4FMzDYSiK6qhpup89BccYiTEF0cU1IGVLpR5nD3GirYpqgXZ1XO7VS3Kv/ltO35ELxiQ8jvUaLGcylvRUDPf3Q@D4BPJrA6RPUlkPNs46ndcnXLkcuu2rPHcxX25XqkPhhPER6lDduSo6y@FRrDu0Fy@EiXxTvIhwLNQSE3wixc5QlvF0KIcj7YTkFCVbam8cPIp8q2wgv4VMWS3dR55h5usyS1a8Y8MJOwFKt13wmdf0KGx/GjXzUpZdOyBNyfQO2yJ08fcoM/UXMY2fhnUghCpRDocvOp0GaumHavSo1SQ8gG//MFvsoUpVyLthS@47nxqwTabWA3CIH@nYcJuUfi4MJhECo6iMCxpFCq5HURFnZRTprb7OZ2u9/keLNcexCRmNiK3f695X3Sb2JbFHb9duwwMXU/Ub)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
c½Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/nQ3nOL////H5UIAA)

Input as a two character string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), 27 bytes

Not as original as @manatwork's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195698/15940), but shorter. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVpDWVNFQ0NDWVnFUBtIGGnqG2lq1v7//9/xvzMA)

```bash
<<<${(#)$(((##$1+##$2)/2))}
```

[Alternative](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/oCgzryRNISZGJTpaWdkiVkNZWcVQG0gYaeobxf7//9/xvzMA) for 30 bytes: `printf \\$[[##8](##$1+##$2)/2]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>24</s> <s>21</s></sup> 14 bytes

```julia
a\b=a+(b-a)÷2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzEmyTZRWyNJN1Hz8Haj/w7FGfnlCuqO6jHqzupcUF4ikFcF56UAeVlwnhOQlwrnRQF5ier/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
CṁC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJD4bmBQyIsIiIsImF6Il0=)

#### Explanation

```
CṁC
     (implicit input)
C    Convert to character code list
 ṁ   Get average
  C  Convert back to letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) ([ASCII-Piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet)), 12 bytes

```
jN LnN FjCjJ
```

ASCII-Piet is a compact encoding for the image-based esolang Piet that encodes each pixel (or codel) of Piet code as a single ASCII character. This ASCII-Piet code translates into the following program:

[image]

Or enlarged to codel size 25:

[image]

Edit: fixed the enlarged version, and golfed two bytes off by rotating the program.

Simply takes two characters from input (Piet can only represent chars on the stack by codepoints), sums them, divides by two, and outputs the result char.

Answer (score 2):

**ABAP**

```
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b0.
    PARAMETERS: p_first  TYPE c LOWER CASE OBLIGATORY,
                p_second TYPE c LOWER CASE OBLIGATORY.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b0.

    START-OF-SELECTION.
    
    WRITE / cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>uccpi( uccp =
         (
            ( cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>uccpi( char = p_first )
              + cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>uccpi( char = p_second ) ) / 2 )
          ).
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Is all of that whitespace necessary, or could some be removed to save bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 5 bytes

```
+2,o;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiKzIsbzsiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiWmEiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 2 bytes

```
mC
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhaLcp2XFCclF0O5CxYlVkFYAA)

```
mC  # implicit input, B flag converts string to byte array
m   # mean
 C  # convert to letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `K`, 2 bytes

```
ṁC
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=%E1%B9%81C&inputs=ac&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 8 bytes

```
ii2+d@'o
```

Try it in [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=AC#ii2%2Bd%40%27o)!

Takes the two letters on stdin with no separator. Very straightforward, `putchar((getchar() + getchar()) / 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 20 <sup><s>21</s></sup> bytes

> -1 byte after seeing in other languages that `[...]>>1` is a shorter way to do `([...])/2` because it has less operator priority!

A 2-parameters problem is the only moment where the double lambda can shine!

```java
a->b->(char)(a+b>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdC9boMwEAfwPU9xYsEogJSMjaCCzp3YWmU4wFCoIQgb1A9l7NZHaF8uL0KvfKaiSJbs04/z/5xji1YeP3dVE4osgkiglHCPWQnvmw1AVipeJxhx8KgA9PmQsOgJa0DjQIXzX@WPqhfpAMMFSoWKbvFAgNOh5YaW2xuD4TZ03Z3RHX7ZGGbU7SmLgbcohnYV1ljsTFgO@/HAXyoeKR4b1yFqLhuhwAFhJ2z417DTYbfvkwEEr1Lxwj41yq5qGkaUjE3NHGfocKtdvj5Au9Eu35@gGduhuoz2T@aCnpEFijqmj0fAOpVTsn4aAN3TTf1Op4JJS/dpNyaaABJ4m0GxBjGBfAbpGvgE@AyCNXgggDM4ToCGOnc/)

Answer (score 2):

### C, 17 bytes

```
f(a,b){a=a+b>>1;}
```

At first I thought

```
f(a,b){a=(a+b)/2;}
```

was the best but then I remembered Cs operation precedent and realized it would be shorter to shift right by 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÇÅAç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPvhVsfDy///j1ZyVNJRclaKBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@f9w@@FWx8PL/yspPGqbpKBUaW@v8z86WslRSUfJWSlWRyFaKRHIrIIwU4DMLKXYWAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ç    | Get ASCII values of both inputs
 ÅA  | Take the mean
   ç | Convert to ASCII char
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 22 bytes

```perl
$_=chr+(ord(<>)+ord)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jY5o0hbI78oRcPGTlMbSGvqG/3/n8hV9S@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 17 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=a+b>>1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM60TZRO8nOztC69r9yZl5yTmlKqoJNcUlKZr5ehh1XZl6JQm5iZp6GpkI1F2dBEZCfpqGkmhyTp6SjkKah7qiuo6DurK6paY1NNhEkW4VLNgUkmwWWrf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
℅⊘ΣＥＳ℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMZyE9MLkkt0vBIzClLTdEILs3V8E0s0PDMKygtCS4BKkrX0NRR8C9KycxLzNHI1AQD6///nd3/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a string of two letters. Explanation:

```
    Ｓ   Input string
   Ｅ    Map over characters
      ι Current character
     ℅  Take the ordinal
  Σ     Take the sum
 ⊘      Halved
℅       Convert to character
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 27 bytes

```
->x,y{(x.ord+y.ord>>1).chr}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Cp7Jao0IvvyhFuxJE2tkZauolZxTV/i8oLSlWSNNLTszJ0VB3VNdRd1bX5EIRTAQKVqELpgAFs9Q1/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:chr((ord(a)+ord(b))//2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSFRJ8kqOaNIQyO/KEUjUVMbRCVpaurrG2n@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 8 bytes

```
,,+_2/.@
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fR0c73khfz@H//8QqAA)**

#### How?

```
, read a character from STDIN and push its ordinal 
, read a character from STDIN and push its ordinal
+ pop y, pop x, push x+y
_ push a zero
2 pop x, push 10*x+2
/ pop y, pop x, push x/y (integer division, rounded towards negative infinity)
. pop x, print byte at (x%256)
@ exit program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
xc z d
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=eGMgeiBk&input=WyJBIiwiQyJd)

Comment: Why not just `xc z d`?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, because beer! Also, lack of practice. But mainly beer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>6</strike> 5 bytes

```
C.OmC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31nPP9f5/3/1FHUdBfUsdQA)

As a bonus, works with more than two letters

Edit: -1 thanks to @randomdude999, wasnt aware that the lambda function implicitly adds the lambda variable

### How it Works

```
C.OmC
   mC - Map (char to int) to the implicit input
 .O    - Take the average
C      - Int to char
```

Comment: Oh wow, I made a solution that was identical to this yesterday but didn't post it, nice one

Comment: You don't need the trailing `d`.

Comment: @randomdude999 good catch

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
toEnum.(`div`2).sum.map fromEnum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BawIxEIXv@RWP2IOi2UOPBQvLIl5UhNKTlhqbLJu6ySyZbKEt/e3bbEE7hxnefG/eNJovtm2HbzXBptytn8v1CtV@j4n6EcL5jmJCRSFFaostBW0wrSluX2dQCj1bAwrtJ1xAaiyS5YRGx2CZFwiUroD7s3fMjgLeyFghRmel2TKWOMiykgtI/TV28y5fhPA6Xy7x9wv/5jscrwLqEYYEcnV9ekpxEzK@0fkc8gFynIf6ts7JdY49DolWoffF9GTcx@l@VnAWXneoI/mRDBh@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - <s>62</s> 60 bytes

I'm certain there's a better way than this:

```
(a,b,c=x=>x.charCodeAt())=>String.fromCharCode(c(a)+c(b)>>1)
```

Would love some feedback!

Example:

```
f=(a,b,c=x=>x.charCodeAt())=>String.fromCharCode(c(a)+c(b)>>1)
f('a','c') // 'b'
```

Comment: Another way to divide by 2 is to delete the last binary digit by doing a right-shift one place. This would be `>>1`. This is of course longer than `/2`, but the advantage is that it has lower precedence in terms of order-of-operations, so you can remove a pair of brackets. This results in a net gain of one character. So `(...)/2` -> `...>>1`

Comment: I count 64 bytes. You don’t need the `0` argument. As far as I know only the function is needed, without the name; so you could use `(a,b,c=x=>x.charCodeAt())=>String.fromCharCode((c(a)+c(b))/2)`, which would be 61 bytes. 60 with @Max’s suggestion.

Comment: Thanks you guys, very clever. I thought about the bitshift but didn't realize it is low in op precedence!

Comment: Write `c` as a helper and take two inputs as `a=>b=>`

Comment: You can reduce it to 58 bytes by currying the function, defining the `c` function inline and doing the division by 2 within it: `a=>b=>String.fromCharCode((c=x=>x.charCodeAt()/2)(a)+c(b))`

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 6 bytes

```
ii+2,H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PzNT20jH4///lCwA)

**Explanation**

```
ii     Push 2 input chars as int to stack
  +    Add them
   2,  Float divide by 2
     H Output as char and halt (Seems to truncate)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
t+~2.`>_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/v0S7zkgvwS7e4f9/p1QA)

**Ungolfed:**

```
   t
  + ~
 2 . `
> _ @

----------------------

t~`           - Read 2 characters from input; change direction to SE after
+2>_          - Add the two top values of the stack, then divide by 2
@             - Print as a character
```

---

**Previous Version (10 bytes):**

```
~.~..+@_2<
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
:V@]
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3AV%40]&i=%22AC%22%0A%22az%22%0A%22dj%22%0A%22Be%22%0A%22Za%22%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

### [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
{+}*2/]''+
```

### Explanation

```
{+}*       # Fold the input string with sums
    2/     # Divide this number by 2
      ]''+ # Put stack into array & convert to string

# Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/P7pau1bLSD9WXV37//@oRAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 6 bytes

Has some trailing garbage, but can't be avoided because all functions have return values.

```
ō/+čč2
```

### Explanation

```
  +čč  Sum two inputs' charcodes
 /   2 Halve the number
ō      Output as a character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 7 bytes

```
ii+2/o@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/z8zU9tIP9/h//@oRAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 9 bytes

```
)**avavL[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f9fU0srsSyxzCf6///EKgA)

If I'm allowed to report the ceiling, can save 2 chars `)**foL[` `fo` is defined as `avpd` which calculates the average and then ceilings it.

```
)** # Map ord(a)
av  # Calculate average
av  # Floor the resulting double
L[  # Int to Char
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 48 bytes

```
f=fromEnum;g a b=toEnum(div((f a)+(f b))2)::Char
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802rSg/1zWvNNc6XSFRIcm2JB/E0UjJLNPQSFNI1NQGkkmamkaaVlbOGYlF/3MTM/MUbBVS8rkUgKCgtCS4pMgnT0FFoTgjv1xBI11BPVFdQT1JXROnvCMB@RSgfIS65n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 26 bytes

Sums the input, divide by 2, and then convert to character.

```erlang
f(X)->[lists:sum(X)div 2].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TSNCU9cuOiezuKTYqrg0F8hNySxTMIrV@5@bmJmnER2rqaBrx6UABJn5VmnlRZklqRppGkqOzkqamjqY4olV2MVTsrCLO6ViF49KBIrr/QcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 5 bytes

```
|M2P;
```

Input must be given without any separator.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%7CM2P%3B&input=az)

Comment: F***... MAWP have a division built-in...

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive well, there are four arithmetic operations: `M`, `A`, `W`, `P`

Comment: @Dion I'm getting used to the lack of subtraction and division. Isn't [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209706/87986) nice, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÇO;ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLu/9eHl//9HKyUq6SgoVSnFAgA)

```
ÇO;ç  # full program
  ;   # divide...
 O    # sum of...
Ç     # charcodes of...
      # implicit input...
  ;   # by 2
   ç  # convert to charcodes, rounding down
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 18 characters

```raku
{($^a..^$^b)[*/2]}
```

Sample run:

```
> {($^a..^$^b)[*/2]}('A', 'C')
B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoFJcmqRg@79aQyUuUU8vTiUuSTNaS98otvZ/cSJEVkPdUV1HQd1ZXdOaCyGWCBKrQhVLAYlloYo5gcRSUcWiQGKJQLH/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python <s>53</s> 46 bytes

thanks to @manatwork recommended not to store inputs in variables.

```
print(chr(int((ord(input())+ord(input()))/2)))
```

Comment: You only use a and b once, so better avoid storing them in variables by inputting them on separate lines. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzmjSANEa@QXpQAZBaUlGpqa2sgcTX0jIPH/vxNXKgA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork yes, tanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 45 chars

```java
char c(char a,char b){return(char)((a+b)/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc@xDoIwFAXQ3a/o1jYiJq5M6ifApHF4lKpFeSXlQaKEX7fSJo4y3eTes9waBtjYVmNdPbxB0u4KSrOCjauOgIxigzUVa8CgyMkZvJ0vrJfznL860k1qe0rbuacnCiX4nieMH7mU2R8AAbwXQBVAvQAOAegFcAoAIph@L7y6g2NKxIAkRilHp6l3GFspBKxLud3JbPKT/9iWjMXOF18)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
C.OCM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31nP39n3/3@lqEQlAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 8 bytes

```
[ + 2/ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqGQma9QXFKUmZderGDNxeXs4RhkpRClAKET/0craCsY6SvE/k9OzMlRMISoVCgAkiX/AQ)

Or if we're allowed to take input in a list, then

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 4 bytes

```
mean
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ - 34 Bytes

```
int f(int a,int b){return(a+b)/2;}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b) / 2;
}
```

**Explanation**

A function that returns the average of two integers, in this case it can be used with ASCII characters.

Comment: you can remove the type names and use just `f(a,b){return(a+b)/2;}` since itll default to `int`

Comment: @sugarfi Thanks for your comment but `implicit int in declarations' is not defined for C++, although it is defined for C (at least for C89).  I even tried it on GCC to make sure, and it doesn't compile if I remove the type names;  but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 14 bytes

```
O A/+A P A P 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLAdZcFVbNjIFWUhRRyALye0H8AUhy1i1suyTZFiWsH89193zopFtcpe7pSqWNfN0T/czPd09TtS9j6Jvb5IsSpfjeL8ox8n87XTYNEfS5K42FJVPi3gFlCfZfW2oTGYCM44nSRazNGXpPLunj6Ye/XT@@QPrVa9Xny6ZX73@4/CS7VWvJ@fv2E/V6@Vn1qvAJ2dXBvb885kB/Xz@4fDq73bBmY0fbfZn729czx5ewbJiMpqGOXN4JWCiwFatYjhke9Xc@fGvOJnBJHn0leH3/f0VDC5DGHQTMGnKEVjDHF1cnBEIPw7IyT76Zhhy@V4AQN6w9SFMlzHn19mIN5vkB@zK9Si4bB1fnNjfLtjhTueQfWT4z//GYbA1EDgHgHE4YwFKDJpNULsI8yK2OXtuNpKsZMmg2YBRWsJlzmSZRTBCwhG8l7OFWyyya38UPHuu9wI6GgmoIzw8PRzY2UH1yYI9TpMyLhZhFDcb8D2NbRgHcVuY4bLWTXmT3Uxucvb8cj2yef9Ni5MpjWTCbG1twKw3FmdChRrdgtGbDIY7HTECdjbitIjNgRdhTjSNo9/YZJ6zbDm7i/NC2sPspBgn90mptMLq6E7P1R6Jp8N6HuswR1re6XDWZZZnwRJoacJZHpfLPGMqKIQYxcVg1YaHME/CuzRWVoAR6fwxzu0I1lOGsK9fmTIuoreIiPhicUlPssH1JOi5sEeBHl6xDo@ZDEeAZOPlwsYtZZLTLoO3dYPFoS@ENmHGjWVVNrUssWkgDB5ooxgogSQB38GyRViUrJzGoCzMSwDLDXAUo7ihEUdPlLHG2XnVWPjscdroRkUGmY@hWybzDMzGiPVGYFqkGCmWiwUSzlVUqRGTfjP@gHaDbNShQnmRQRxDwsLIlZYLVj5Z@lSLgRMcwOTVx6SFZqogo3wnXLXRbjQ1TNN5ZO95bo@jgzisnSAHs2WahvmT6Wi1P5fG9ny0tGW0oJRfZivStEQPl5BJYZOnh8dH725/2Tr7@cJw2FR7l2zU66/r3aopfn969YrGMs5JZZiN2b@WoXpFtQ/mErvrSwgC3luai9MNXJDwXl24jnmhVJkvM9yhgUy6TjkvbJUr6QBAaJdJxGj2bjm59vdG0g6x0W1KD9qAYgHHqpzYAAX/t9N03FJ5h4qOi0pWFcCh0ApEORPr13D7rLdb9xOdx1g8YK0yX8YtiEE9jiEJ45MQMghOtDCyWhUJ6Cf6LusO0fHlaD5PYeauzsCrvlZufc8h58c9Ms28WzMzRRuzv9RGCNpynqa2aarLPBcqxP9gcrZmMlbhD4cfz12sxSLQ4PX0uud5HoQTuAKv6q1I/oi/lAwfAyNGDW@RAXhz8cOnz92gp0o6Zjis6vigT188dgFwcnp27LAJJMdBQ4e2XA/TcBQu3DTOqAMwuFJtkeAMzt1rZKwKYm3C0oYFx06ol4BavE9cDKCoJDip80Y0W6zsAJGUjKoUgjQlI1ymeEzKaGo7wMxaFwUcMfkXYZ2yDq0@w1UEIEBCsQ@DLMzb5JRULzvBWsjyAVXhCkHtZplj6aKO83rEn6swgwaKcrtY@BIWruvOIePZvO39PsG/CvkRkKBVcHQflyk0i3ab9rKNO4QlcpxkfJBMbJv2ExuCaJqjLS7EKedimwNvsNFWeHBqA8R6x2I90TliNpCEDJS9SJLMnZWVR5U/Aq9n3lUzKGlSrDG3gMFogPgLFvNFnNnGwm4rb1GrAFYFM1EpIR4D39v7icZlc2GLjmQCpo/RKWjhIGRd7O8ADr0DveEasLQKLxsGWSegVghPLCC5pBv00FpENWpwAuabPUtFY@XJL@BJ/Du0cXja1/zcqu063Qm2MJOtAc/WwgNWSeu8GPCfrb7sEzcEss58sgK1zqkttrEGcVWEhsM9XjWWa@lQiV5Rc2hvFyhYPwzrwkAntD7mupBJeauCqgksL3GYSbWvlTBZs8wdkLlFsnBRsYAHQ1x8kDSxnzXqWLtNF6luF6Ej0ebeULvdUGZtv3UKsMeGN87UUcsN85dloXZfx4To9YRBHW0Q5UnIl5iSMbSM7RHddKO@2@JWimjo@5mKJV/sOfa/dBjEBhAKh/GUB8pLn28O1Sgs1UN2nb1ORRNX31EXh27UpWcpc4T0q7sWnUa0Y6tet1cIOdXubGBhtTxv4MFZ40Hs6yYWZhtccwgTmEpIAGqQTRkysG7gkoegQbdL@iRRVDJXN1owWtZO/853idnZTMz2d4W2Nwv9k9isOSSuDjTmm14OJO2C9YB1e5plwgL1PThn3R6csZ4J9n8QvQ/psYYNAoTSun014inKiWh/6EmufU7tihMQ/83VA0GT5ArcESjBYomB73hlmMZ5bBUsm0MPnaRlkrHH8Al4Y@M53EnL@D7OQWYxz@KsTEK8RcBJnrPHmE3DhxiAUhHCSzYLsyWEz9NbHEXv7pBxoIKYKJZpiT8a0OI64SlI18SoJVcoM@U0ZEU96nsd6b1uiIbt11Ae3c/DFGvjE3idjdN4zG4rs2@1lmf8JhozY5HKmSEq63bVOyd4Q0Idw/QXnQf3KVhXCh8mvVpeDOpZ8YCZh3/fPAYo2pe/t7WZABywWqNIgy4zsiHq8ISkKrm@qAOI3Qqg2hhd0BAOJYbWfDzvs1k8ixYYZhkb3h78v64M/wJXhsqVrQ2@BNIX6crB6@yLVTeYjNMHrAbwNcJXBXRrk53Vi3ZPZR5TgTavXaU/9GVTbTgwJWUq0fJf/xt5mYMMNVp@YPVNdK3NXcUGVdatT//wRUb1ttVNBnGN2m1Gp0LCoMZRUJM20iRKIKLT0WLC5F/BPfGrl9lo1rxjZu8ixU7rXTtCDfkDv79r0PJeXBkCo8PqmAVo/Y6UyYuHq8/Cbq2hvRJErygdrJY8f1PJ2@W6D/C19B4N/oeGCA3DJ25FpJt/3Q6ZvZEPHuKqnR42SdQgiPgXk/QgREeeBFh9HE9CSJLgmeowkwwmkzH9iBRGJZQpazuysOfEEc5eucWiMl0DoRuUPyTMwiTDZpWF@X3kklLHge8PHH@uovsl/veN7ZE19Wvcy7ejZvxv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 32 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rc69boMwFAXgnac4G3ZVgdQRiUiUiSET6tKoqm7B/AnsyDapQpVnpxclU7LGi@Vz7fPZVTTSan4GVXnsqdf4C4IAONGIJhF5R/ZFprttR7ou6U4s0URH8R15U2gvIzdP8Zvk03Zl5Ze1ajBxkSDbugSZtXQ@lN72uv2SCT5075GyAl5HTv2oRSPCLHwN81BKTuMYZWfmsb7OQai4myqvLH474xSyMi@K7Y@zQu/gOwU6KUutgmnAXSBdg/vuFWJleZJCN2V5UGpWhicp9U0ZHpR3VhQr9/kn53TNL8Fl/Qc)

```scala
z=>(z.map(_.toInt).sum/2).toChar
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
int a,b;scanf("%c,%c",&a,&b);printf("%c",a+b>>1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@n5lXopCbmJmnoVkNZifqJFkXJyfmpWkoqSbrqCYr6agl6qglaVoXFAGlwaJKOonaSXZ2hprW/2v/O@o4AwA)

Got the idea of bit-shift operators from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195649/106829) answer

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**, 134 bytes

```
var s=readLine(),a=readLine();print(Character(UnicodeScalar((s?.compactMap{$0.asciiValue}[0])!+(a?.compactMap{$0.asciiValue}[0])!/2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
a,b=gets.split;puts"#{((a.ord+b.ord)/2).chr}"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN3UTdZJs01NLivWKC3IyS6wLSkuKlZSrNTQS9fKLUrSTQKSmvpGmXnJGUa0SRBNU74LFKQpZECYA)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWNxUKlJSrNdJTS4r18otStGEMOztDTb3kjKJaJYg6qPIFi1O4siBMAA) taking input separated by newlines

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 22 bytes

```
:*&:ord|+:+|~:/&2|:chr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW26y01Kzyi1JqtK20a-qs9NWMaqySM4ogkpsKSkuKFdyio5VSlHQUlLKUYmMhEgsWpyhkQZgA)

### Explanation

```
:* & :ord | +:+ | ~:/ & 2 | :chr

:* & :ord |                       # Map with .ord, then
            +:+ |                 # sum, then
                  ~:/ & 2 |       # integer divide by two, then
                            :chr  # convert to character
```

Answer (score 0):

## Uiua, 18 bytes

```
⍜∩utf(⌊÷2+)
```

[Try It](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4o2c4oipdXRmKOKMisO3MispIEBBIEBCCg==)

Explanation

```
⍜∩utf(⌊÷2+)
⍜∩utf # convert both chars to ints, 
      # apply the operation in parentheses, and undo the char to int conversion
     (⌊÷2+) # calculate a floored avg
         + # sum both elements
       ÷2 # divide by two
      ⌊ # floor the result
```