# Mirror a String in Place

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-memory

Write a program that takes a string as input and modifies it by reversing the string in its place by mirroring the position. The first position goes to last, second to second last and so it goes on. In simple words, the string would be mirrored.

"In Place" means the program should use \$O(1)\$ additional memory regardless of the length of the string

### Test Cases

Input: `"Hello, World!"`
Output: `"!dlroW ,olleH"`

Input: `"Hello"`
Output: `"olleH"`

Input: `"A man a plan a canal Panama"`
Output: `"amanaP lanac a nalp a nam A"`

Input: `"123456789"`
Output: `"987654321"`

Input: `""`
Output: `""`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because the requirement to not allocate memory for additional copies of the input string is objectively unobservable - does creating memory for every character of the input but the last count as making memory for the input string? Does making memory for individual characters count as making memory for the input string? And what about languages where you can't directly inspect memory (like interpreted languages)?

Comment: I think it would be impossible as you said for interpreted languages and restrict it to compiled language, I must remove that requirement, doing it now

Comment: well, my original intent by this was that answers be in compiled languages but fine, I am removing the condition

Comment: I suggest using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) next time to get challenge feedback before posting. It's a good way of making sure there's no problems with questions :)

Comment: thanks and sorry :') @lyxal

Comment: It's still unclear what it means to reverse the string "in place" - saying that all operations should be applied to the same variable isn't objective because then that definition falls apart for languages that don't have variables or operate on stacks/tapes/other data structures. And even when there are variables, it's still [an unobservable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/78850), which is disallowed in questions.

Comment: [Very closely related, if not duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242/114446)

Comment: Did you mean to say the program should use O(1) memory regardless of the length of the string? That would be observable and force "in-place" allocation while still allowing temporary variables

Comment: by reversing string in place, i simply mean to mirror this, either i do not know how to convey it or something, it has nothing to dealt with variables, just reversing the position as specified is what i meant

Comment: @mousetail probably, I just wanted the answer to be in compiled language so I said that. but its fine now to use interpreted language

Comment: I don't think this is substantially different from [Reverse stdin and place on stdout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242/reverse-stdin-and-place-on-stdout), the requirement to reverse inplace being unobservable.

Comment: @ATaco that's not a duplicate, the restriction completely changes the challenge

Comment: no @ATaco because it is restricted to standard IO

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz Restricting IO does not effect duplicate status

Comment: It does in *very* rare cases, usually to a community vote.

Comment: may i get some link to these rules, and are the current edits fine to reopen the question? what should I edit [next time I will definitely use sandbox]

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/91213

Comment: Nobody really agrees which one of these answers are "hard rules" and which ones are "recommendations" unfortunatly

Comment: I don't want to dissuade you from challenge writing as we always need more challenges, This challenge is unfortunately too similar too the standard Reverse challenge (In my personal opinion). To keep this challenge, it'd need to be substantially different with explicitly observable criteria. I can't point you in that direction without coming up with a challenge for myself, though :P.

Comment: Then I am thinking @ATaco that I pass the requirement Mousetail give to make it a restricted memory question.

Comment: @lyxal O(1) extra memory usage means for any given interpreter / runtime you choose. You may claim a size of memory X MiB. And your program must output the correct result for any input with Y MiB ASCII characters in at most (X+Y) MiB and do not trigger an out of memory error. There is nothing different than limiting the time usage in P or in O(n^3).

Answer (score 2):

## x86 assembly (Linux) - <s>42</s> 26 bytes

`F6 D6 29 D4 B0 03 89 E1 CD 80 01 C1 43 89 DA 49 39 E1 7C 06 B0 04 CD 80 EB F5`

This is my first Assembly program. Reads from stdin, then outputs to stdout in reverse order. **[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/pXjYH0)**

```
not dh       ; sys_read count = edx = 65280
sub esp,edx  ; allocate 65280 bytes on stack

mov al,3     ; 0x03 = "read" syscall
mov ecx,esp  ; sys_read buf = ecx = stack pointer
int 0x80     ; eax = sys_read(stdin, esp, 65280)

add ecx,eax  ; add read bytes to stack pointer

inc ebx      ; sys_write fd = 1 = stdout
mov edx,ebx  ; sys_write count = 1

reverse:
dec ecx      ;
cmp ecx,esp  ; check if we've gone too far
jl done      ;

mov al,4     ; 0x04 = "write" syscall
int 0x80     ; eax = sys_write(stdout, ecx, 1)

jmp reverse

done:
```

Disassembly

```
0:  f6 d6                   not    dh
2:  29 d4                   sub    esp,edx
4:  b0 03                   mov    al,0x3
6:  89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp
8:  cd 80                   int    0x80
a:  01 c1                   add    ecx,eax
c:  43                      inc    ebx
d:  89 da                   mov    edx,ebx
0000000f <reverse>:
f:  49                      dec    ecx
10: 39 e1                   cmp    ecx,esp
12: 7c 06                   jl     1a <done>
14: b0 04                   mov    al,0x4
16: cd 80                   int    0x80
18: eb f5                   jmp    f <reverse>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>139</s> <s>134</s> 132 bytes

```c
#define C strlen(a[1])
main(int n,char**a){for(n=0;n<C/2;){*(a[1]+n)^=**a=*(a[1]+n)^*(a[1]+C-n-1);*(a[1]+C-n++-1)^=**a;}puts(a[1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCgIhGITvPcUPXdRNaruah/AFukfBj7kl6N/i2mnZZzexYC8z8zEDY@XT2lK2Dzd4cmBgyik4Ynjtb3wT0RPzlIF29oVJCOTz8E6M9EHRyeyPis@ibTvid117veI/GUmy52qlrqvcxmoZP3n6famllHKGiAQIY2hmkTDApWrELw)

Thanks for the "you can use `puts` suggestion from Neil that saved 2 bytes...

OK, assuming I understand the goal (which is big assumption), I think this one does the right thing...  It reverses the string passed as the first commandline argument, then prints it.  No additional storage is allocated to effect the reversal.

It works by XOR'ing each character of the string with the one it should be swapped with, then XOR'ing that composite value with each of the original characters.  The temporary storage needed to complete the work are a `char` for holding the XOR composite, and an `int` string offset.  The code overloads variables the compiler created for other purposes to avoid allocating additional memory for those temporary variables.

```c
#define C strlen(a[1])       - just a shortcut to save space
main(int n,char**a){ ... }   - standard "this is a C program" stuff
for(n=0;n<C/2;){ ... }       - loop C/2 times (half the length of the string)
**a=*(a[1]+n)^*(a[1]+C-n-1); - set "*a[0]" to a composite of current swap chars
*(a[1]+n)^=**a...            - use composite to swap first char (w/ XOR)
*(a[1]+C-n++-1)^=**a;        - and repeat with the second char, increment "n"
puts(a[1]);                  - output the reversed string
```

If the rules allow for temporary variables, this could be shorter.

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcVBCgIxDEbhq3TZpim4LxW8gScQ/iSOFqZ1KC4E8ex1dPHep@mmOmdD7V4ZLGxB7xhEYBImy@/lMbyV2u368lIoRvAh5JTsKDmQxHgpZHvyM2@j9ufiCSF/5pwn19Ad3Lb@UXSs7ry/4Qs "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Always use hard-coded strings as the first parameter to `printf` e.g. `printf("%s",a[1]);`, otherwise the user could insert format specifiers and cause undefined behaviour. In this case you could probably use `puts` instead.

Comment: re: ceilingcat's MUCH shorter version...  I think that's different enough that it warrants being posted as a separate answer.  Also, it's sort of what I was thinking when I wrote "If the rules allow for temporary variables", so I think it's a different idea entirely.

Comment: Re:unsafe printf() use, I agree but for golf contests I think that's OK?  But the puts() call is shorter too, so I switch it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 8 bytes

```
reverse!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqsUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYM3FVa2g5JGak5OvoxCeX5SToqgE5QNpR4XcxDyFRIWCHDCVnJiXmKMQACRzE4GyhkbGJqZm5haWQLaSQi1X9P@i1LLUouJUxf@xQI0FCnr/AQ)

Builtin.
The documentation (and source code) for [reverse!](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-reverse!,sequences.html) corroborates its O(1) additional memory usage beyond the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 57 bytes

```perl
for$l(0...5*length){s/.{$l}\K(.)(.*)(.)(.{$l})/$3$2$1$4/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9C8IwGIT3/IpXGrAVTfyqH4ODm@Di5iJI1Ldt5G1SkiiI@NeN1cXlnrvjuAYd5TEW1nFKh0KIvEdoylBlTy/Fk9PrsE1Flope9sO3ySSf8DEf8al8xYQfV1erTbfbd3hH51EKWbKkvdIefGVdQAenB6hCtbwFqHVZBRPghKBNQ@r8ADT2VlZxg0S2D3vr6NJhv8TWUCsDCtrhF2dlFMGu1Vqx0XgyzWfzxZIN//Ztm6Ct8XHQfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 14 bytes

```
s=>s.reverse()
```

Try it:

```js
f=s=>s.reverse()

;[
  'Hello, World!',
  'Hello',
  'A man a plan a canal Panama',
  '123456789',
  ''
].forEach(s=>console.log(f([...s]).join``))
```